# What is Scala's yield?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, yield

I understand Ruby and Python's yield. What does Scala's yield do?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

It is used in [sequence comprehensions](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111) (like Python's list-comprehensions and generators, where you may use `yield` too).

It is applied in combination with `for` and writes a new element into the resulting sequence.

Simple example (from [scala-lang](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/225))

```
/** Turn command line arguments to uppercase */
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val res = for (a <- args) yield a.toUpperCase
    println("Arguments: " + res.toString)
  }
}
```

The corresponding expression in F# would be

```
[ for a in args -> a.toUpperCase ]
```

or

```
from a in args select a.toUpperCase
```

in Linq.

Ruby's `yield` has a different effect.

Comment: So why would I use yield instead of map? This map code is equivalent val res = args.map(_.toUpperCase) , right?

Comment: In case you like the syntax better. Also, as alexey points out, comprehensions also provide nice syntax for accessing flatMap, filter and foreach.

Comment: I would much prefer the args map {_ toUpperCase} syntax personally as it "feels" much more OO. It seems more in keeping with the Scala aim of delivering via library support what is only available in other languages via bespoke constructs and keywords

Comment: Right. If you just have a simple map -- one generator with no if -- I'd certainly say calling map is more readable. If you have a several generators depending on each other, and/or filters, you may prefer a for expression.

Comment: Please note that the example given is not equivalent to the map expression: it's the same. A for comprehension is translated to calls to map, flatMap and filter.

Comment: I think I got it:val unorderedGuesses = guessesForSymbol.map {
      case (symbol, guesses) => secretsForSymbol.getOrElse(symbol,0) min(guesses)
    } not sure it brings much to the table

Comment: This is true in this case, but it is actually a more general construct, see the most upvoted answer (@Tempus IMHO you should consider accepting it).

Comment: The answer starts like this: "It is used in sequence comprehensions (like Python's list-comprehensions and generators, where you may use yield too)."
This mistakenly leads one to think that yield in Scala is similar to yield in Python. This is not the case. In Python, yield is used in the context of coroutines (or continuations) whilst it is not the case in Scala. For more clarification, please visit this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201882/implementing-yield-yield-return-using-scala-continuations

Comment: As I was learning scala, I didn't understand why a flatMap which maps and then flattens was necessary, but given time I am unable to go on without the convenience it provides. Just try executing `List(List(1, 2), List(3,4,5), List(6)).flatMap(identity)` which will show the amazing map reduce or group by this provides. Yield expands for to either `flatMap` or `withFilter (cond) map(func)` and no yield expands for to `foreach`

Answer (score 885):

I think the accepted answer is great, but it seems many people have failed to grasp some fundamental points.

First, Scala's `for` comprehensions are equivalent to Haskell's `do` notation, and it is nothing more than a syntactic sugar for composition of multiple monadic operations. As this statement will most likely not help anyone who needs help, let's try again… :-)

Scala's `for` comprehensions is syntactic sugar for composition of multiple operations with map, `flatMap` and `filter`. Or `foreach`. Scala actually translates a `for`-expression into calls to those methods, so any class providing them, or a subset of them, can be used with for comprehensions.

First, let's talk about the translations. There are very simple rules:

1. This

   ```
   for(x <- c1; y <- c2; z <-c3) {...}
   ```

   is translated into

   ```
   c1.foreach(x => c2.foreach(y => c3.foreach(z => {...})))
   ```
2. This

   ```
   for(x <- c1; y <- c2; z <- c3) yield {...}
   ```

   is translated into

   ```
   c1.flatMap(x => c2.flatMap(y => c3.map(z => {...})))
   ```
3. This

   ```
   for(x <- c; if cond) yield {...}
   ```

   is translated on Scala 2.7 into

   ```
   c.filter(x => cond).map(x => {...})
   ```

   or, on Scala 2.8, into

   ```
   c.withFilter(x => cond).map(x => {...})
   ```

   with a fallback into the former if method `withFilter` is not available but `filter` is. Please see the section below for more information on this.
4. This

   ```
   for(x <- c; y = ...) yield {...}
   ```

   is translated into

   ```
   c.map(x => (x, ...)).map((x,y) => {...})
   ```

When you look at very simple `for` comprehensions, the `map`/`foreach` alternatives look, indeed, better. Once you start composing them, though, you can easily get lost in parenthesis and nesting levels. When that happens, `for` comprehensions are usually much clearer.

I'll show one simple example, and intentionally omit any explanation. You can decide which syntax was easier to understand.

```
l.flatMap(sl => sl.filter(el => el > 0).map(el => el.toString.length))
```

or

```
for {
  sl <- l
  el <- sl
  if el > 0
} yield el.toString.length
```

---

#### `withFilter`

Scala 2.8 introduced a method called `withFilter`, whose main difference is that, instead of returning a new, filtered, collection, it filters on-demand. The `filter` method has its behavior defined based on the strictness of the collection. To understand this better, let's take a look at some Scala 2.7 with `List` (strict) and `Stream` (non-strict):

```
scala> var found = false
found: Boolean = false

scala> List.range(1,10).filter(_ % 2 == 1 && !found).foreach(x => if (x == 5) found = true else println(x))
1
3
7
9

scala> found = false
found: Boolean = false

scala> Stream.range(1,10).filter(_ % 2 == 1 && !found).foreach(x => if (x == 5) found = true else println(x))
1
3
```

The difference happens because `filter` is immediately applied with `List`, returning a list of odds -- since `found` is `false`. Only then `foreach` is executed, but, by this time, changing `found` is meaningless, as `filter` has already executed.

In the case of `Stream`, the condition is not immediatelly applied. Instead, as each element is requested by `foreach`, `filter` tests the condition, which enables `foreach` to influence it through `found`. Just to make it clear, here is the equivalent for-comprehension code:

```
for (x <- List.range(1, 10); if x % 2 == 1 && !found) 
  if (x == 5) found = true else println(x)

for (x <- Stream.range(1, 10); if x % 2 == 1 && !found) 
  if (x == 5) found = true else println(x)
```

This caused many problems, because people expected the `if` to be considered on-demand, instead of being applied to the whole collection beforehand.

Scala 2.8 introduced `withFilter`, which is *always* non-strict, no matter the strictness of the collection. The following example shows `List` with both methods on Scala 2.8:

```
scala> var found = false
found: Boolean = false

scala> List.range(1,10).filter(_ % 2 == 1 && !found).foreach(x => if (x == 5) found = true else println(x))
1
3
7
9

scala> found = false
found: Boolean = false

scala> List.range(1,10).withFilter(_ % 2 == 1 && !found).foreach(x => if (x == 5) found = true else println(x))
1
3
```

This produces the result most people expect, without changing how `filter` behaves. As a side note, `Range` was changed from non-strict to strict between Scala 2.7 and Scala 2.8.

Comment: There is a new method withFilter in scala 2.8.
for(x <- c; if cond) yield {...}
is translate to
c.withFilter(x => cond).map(x => {...}) in scala2.8.

Comment: @Eastsun True enough, though there's also automatic fallback. `withFilter` is supposed to be non-strict as well, even for strict collections, which deserves some explanation. I'll consider this...

Comment: @Daniel: There is a great treatment of this very subject in "Programming in Scala", by Odersky, et al. (I'm sure you know that already). +1 for showing it.

Comment: The first 2 points are correct with:

1.
`for(x <- c; y <- x; z <-y) {...}`
is translated into
`c.foreach(x => x.foreach(y => y.foreach(z => {...})))`

2.
`for(x <- c; y <- x; z <- y) yield {...}`
is translated into
`c.flatMap(x => x.flatMap(y => y.map(z => {...})))`

Comment: Is this `for(x <- c; y = ...) yield {...}` really translated into `c.map(x => (x, ...)).map((x,y) => {...})`? I think it's translated into `c.map(x => (x, ...)).map(x => { ...use x._1 and x._2 here...})` or I'm missing something?

Comment: @prostynick you are correct--you can't pattern match the left side of lambda functions in scala. So it would look something like `c.map(x => (x, y)).map(xAndY => {val x = xAndY._1; val y = xAndY._2; ...})`

Comment: I am re-writing a codebase from Scala to NestJS; this literally helped me understand the syntax and original logic, thanks. Best answer!

Answer (score 24):

Yes, as Earwicker said, it's pretty much the equivalent to LINQ's `select` and has very little to do with Ruby's and Python's `yield`. Basically, where in C# you would write

```
from ... select ???
```

in Scala you have instead

```
for ... yield ???
```

It's also important to understand that `for`-comprehensions don't just work with sequences, but with any type which defines certain methods, just like LINQ:

- If your type defines just `map`, it allows `for`-expressions consisting of a
  single generator.
- If it defines `flatMap` as well as `map`, it allows `for`-expressions consisting
  of several generators.
- If it defines `foreach`, it allows `for`-loops without yield (both with single and multiple generators).
- If it defines `filter`, it allows `for`-filter expressions starting with an `if`
  in the `for` expression.

Comment: @Eldritch Conundrum - Which interestingly enough is the same order in which the original SQL spec outlines.  Somewhere along the way the SQL language inverted the order, but it makes complete sense to first describe what you are pulling from followed by what you expect to get out of it.

Answer (score 15):

Unless you get a better answer from a Scala user (which I'm not), here's my understanding.

It only appears as part of an expression beginning with `for`, which states how to generate a new list from an existing list.

Something like:

```
var doubled = for (n <- original) yield n * 2
```

So there's one output item for each input (although I believe there's a way of dropping duplicates).

This is quite different from the "imperative continuations" enabled by yield in other languages, where it provides a way to generate a list of any length, from some imperative code with almost any structure.

(If you're familiar with C#, it's closer to [LINQ's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) `select` operator than it is to `yield return`).

Answer (score 13):

Consider the following [for-comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension)

```
val A = for (i <- Int.MinValue to Int.MaxValue; if i > 3) yield i
```

It may be helpful to read it out loud as follows

*"**For** each integer `i`, **if** it is greater than `3`, then **yield** (produce) `i` and add it to the list `A`."*

In terms of mathematical [set-builder notation](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/set-builder-notation.html), the above for-comprehension is analogous to

[image: set-notation]

which may be read as

*"**For** each integer [image: i], **if** it is greater than [image: 3], then it **is a member** of the set [image: A]."*

or alternatively as

*"[image: A] is the set of all integers [image: i], such that each [image: i] is greater than [image: 3]."*

Answer (score 12):

**The keyword `yield` in Scala is simply syntactic sugar** which can be easily replaced by a `map`, as [Daniel Sobral already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/578288) in detail.

On the other hand, **`yield` is absolutely misleading if** you are looking for generators (or continuations) similar to [those in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). See this SO thread for more information: [What is the preferred way to implement 'yield' in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303166/preferred-way-to-implement-yield-in-scala/11277282#11277282)

Answer (score 7):

Yield is similar to for loop which has a buffer that we cannot see and for each increment, it keeps adding next item to the buffer. When the for loop finishes running, it would return the collection of all the yielded values. Yield can be used as simple arithmetic operators or even in combination with arrays.
Here are two simple examples for your better understanding

```
scala>for (i <- 1 to 5) yield i * 3
```

res: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(3, 6, 9, 12, 15)

```
scala> val nums = Seq(1,2,3)
nums: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val letters = Seq('a', 'b', 'c')
letters: Seq[Char] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val res = for {
     |     n <- nums
     |     c <- letters
     | } yield (n, c)
```

res: Seq[(Int, Char)] = List((1,a), (1,b), (1,c), (2,a), (2,b), (2,c), (3,a), (3,b), (3,c))

Hope this helps!!

Comment: When answering a question this old (over 9 years ago) it is helpful to point out how your answer is different from all the other answers already submitted.

Comment: I thought clarifying the doubt is important and not to give the different answer since even I'm also a beginner who is learning this language. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
val aList = List( 1,2,3,4,5 )

val res3 = for ( al <- aList if al > 3 ) yield al + 1
val res4 = aList.filter(_ > 3).map(_ + 1)

println( res3 )
println( res4 )
```

These two pieces of code are equivalent.

```
val res3 = for (al <- aList) yield al + 1 > 3
val res4 = aList.map( _+ 1 > 3 )

println( res3 ) 
println( res4 )
```

These two pieces of code are also equivalent.

Map is as flexible as yield and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
val doubledNums = for (n <- nums) yield n * 2
val ucNames = for (name <- names) yield name.capitalize
```

Notice that both of those for-expressions use the **yield** keyword:

Using **yield** after **for** is the “secret sauce” that says, “I want to yield a new collection from the existing collection that I’m iterating over in the for-expression, using the algorithm shown.”

taken from [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/for-expressions.html#the-yield-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Scala [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/for-expressions.html#:%7E:text=Using%20yield%20after%20for%20is%20the%20%E2%80%9Csecret%20sauce%E2%80%9D%20that%20says%2C%20%E2%80%9CI%20want%20to%20yield%20a%20new%20collection%20from%20the%20existing%20collection%20that%20I%E2%80%99m%20iterating%20over%20in%20the%20for%2Dexpression%2C%20using%20the%20algorithm%20shown.%E2%80%9D), it clearly says "yield a new collection from the existing collection".

Another Scala [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/111#:%7E:text=Scala%20offers%20a%20lightweight%20notation%20for%20expressing%20sequence%20comprehensions.%20Comprehensions%20have%20the%20formfor%C2%A0(enums)%C2%A0yield%C2%A0e%2C%20where%C2%A0enums%C2%A0refers%20to%20a%20semicolon%2Dseparated%20list%20of%20enumerators.%20An%20enumerator%20is%20either%20a%20generator%20which%20introduces%20new%20variables%2C%20or%20it%20is%20a%20filter.) says, "Scala offers a lightweight notation for expressing **sequence comprehensions**. Comprehensions have the form `for` (enums) `yield e`, where enums refers to a semicolon-separated list of enumerators. An enumerator is either a generator which introduces new variables, or it is a filter. "

Answer (score -4):

yield is more flexible than map(), see example below

```
val aList = List( 1,2,3,4,5 )

val res3 = for ( al <- aList if al > 3 ) yield al + 1 
val res4 = aList.map( _+ 1 > 3 ) 

println( res3 )
println( res4 )
```

yield will print result like:  List(5, 6), which is good

while map() will return result like:  List(false, false, true, true, true), which probably is not what you intend.

Comment: That comparison is wrong. You are comparing two different things. The expression in yield is in no way doing the same thing as the expression in map. Also, it does not show the "flexibility" of yield compared to map at all.