# Scala's for-comprehensions: vital feature or syntactic sugar?

Tags: scala, list-comprehension

When I first started looking at Scala, I liked the look of for-comprehensions. They seemed to be a bit like the foreach loops I was used to from Java 5, but with functional restrictions and a lot of sweet syntactic niceness.

But as I've absorbed the Scala style, I find that every time I could use a for-comprension I'm using `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, `reduce` and `foreach` instead. The intention of the code seems clearer to me that way, with fewer potential hidden surprises, and they're usually shorter code too.

As far as I'm aware, for-comprehensions are always compiled down into these methods anyway, so I'm wondering: what are they actually for? Am I missing some functional revalation (it wouldn't be the first time)? Do for-comprehensions do something the other features can't, or would at least be much clumsier at? Do they shine under a particular use case? Is it really just a matter of personal taste?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/can-someone-explain-scalas-yield. That question wondered what `yield` did, this one wonders what's its purpose. The answers are about the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/can-someone-explain-scalas-yield). The short answer is that for-comprehensions can be more readable. In particular, if you have many nested generators, the actual scope of what you are doing becomes more clear, and you don't need huge indents.

Answer (score 12):

Another great use of for-comprehension is for internal DSL.  [ScalaQL](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~dspiewak/papers/scalaql.pdf) is a great example of this.  It can turn this

```
val underAge = for { 
  p <- Person 
  c <- Company 
  if p.company is c 
  if p.age < 14 
} yield p
```

into this

```
SELECT p.* FROM people p JOIN companies c ON p.company_id = c.id WHERE p.age < 14
```

and a whole lot more.

Comment: @Erik It worked when I tried it.  It's a link to a PDF file.  If you still can not download the file, just google it:

ScalaQL: Language-Integrated Database Queries for Scala
by Daniel Spiewak and Tian Zhao

Comment: Downvoted: the actual question is whether there's any advantage of for-comprehensions over their desugaring - and you can write that code also in desugared form.
ScalaQuery is a better example, since it has an available production-quality implementation. That paper glimpses over too many important details to be recommended.

Answer (score 10):

for-comprehensions are syntactic sugar, but that doesn't mean they aren't vital.  They are usually more concise than their expanded form, which is nice, but perhaps more importantly they help programmers from imperative languages use functional constructs.

When I first started with Scala I used for-comprehensions a lot, because they were familiar.  Then I almost stopped completely, because I felt like using the underlying methods was more explicit and therefore clearer.  Now I'm back to using for-comprehensions because I think they better express the intent of what I'm doing rather than the means of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

In some cases, for comprehensions can express intent better, so when they do, use them.

Also note that with for comprehensions, you get *pattern matching* for free. For example, iterating over a Map is much simpler with for comprehension:

`for ((key, value) <- map) println (key + "-->" + value)`

than with foreach:

`map foreach { case (key, value) => println (key + "-->" + value) }`

Answer (score 3):

You are right. The for-comprehension is syntactic sugar. I believe the underlying methods are more succinct and easier to read, once you are used to them.

Compare the following equivalent statements:

```
1. for (i <- 1 to 100; if (i % 3 == 0)) yield Math.pow(i, 2)
2. (1 to 100).filter(_ % 3 == 0).map(Math.pow(_, 2))
```

In my opinion, the addition of the semicolon in #1 distracts from the sense that this is a single chained statement. There is also a sense that i is a var (is it 1, or is it 99, or something inbetween?) which detracts from an otherwise functional style.

Option 2 is more evidently a chain of method calls on objects. Each link in the chain clearly stating its responsibility. There are no intermediate variables.

Perhaps for comprehensions are included as a convenience for developers transitioning from Java. Regardless, which is chosen is a matter of style and preference.

Comment: "once you are used to them" - exactly. Once I understood monads, I switched to the underlying methods. The for comprehension was a useful link before that.

Comment: You need no semicolon in 1 at all: `for (i <- 1 to 100 if (i % 3 == 0)) yield Math.pow(i, 2)`. Moreover, you can replace parentheses with braces to activate semicolon inference.

Comment: Thanks @Blaisorblade I wonder if the semicolon was needed back in 2009.