# Implementing yield (yield return) using Scala continuations

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, yield, continuations, yield-return

How might one implement C# `yield return` using Scala continuations? I'd like to be able to write Scala `Iterator`s in the same style. A stab is in the comments on [this Scala news post](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2096), but it doesn't work (tried using the Scala 2.8.0 beta). Answers in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655738/does-scala-have-an-equivalent-to-c-yield) suggest this is possible, but although I've been playing with delimited continuations for a while, I can't seem to exactly wrap my head around how to do this.

Comment: What doesn't work about that example? It doesn't compile, or it doesn't produce the expected results? There is a mention that, for it to work, it might be necessary to have a CPS-aware `foreach`, but, at any rate, it would be helpful knowing what the problem is.

Comment: You may want to check Miles Sabin's answer to a similar question I had http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137619/scala-equivalent-to-python-generators/2146456#2146456. Not sure it that gets you closer.

Comment: There are at least two other answers to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655738/does-scala-have-an-equivalent-to-c-sharp-yield
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137619/scala-equivalent-to-python-generators

There's also an answer to the issue of how to make it compatible with `for` statements:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934226/continuations-and-for-comprehensions-whats-the-incompatibility

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Before we introduce continuations we need to build some infrastructure.
Below is a [trampoline](http://blog.richdougherty.com/2009/04/tail-calls-tailrec-and-trampolines.html) that operates on `Iteration` objects.
An iteration is a computation that can either `Yield` a new value or it can be `Done`.

```
sealed trait Iteration[+R]
case class Yield[+R](result: R, next: () => Iteration[R]) extends Iteration[R]
case object Done extends Iteration[Nothing]

def trampoline[R](body: => Iteration[R]): Iterator[R] = {
  def loop(thunk: () => Iteration[R]): Stream[R] = {
    thunk.apply match {
      case Yield(result, next) => Stream.cons(result, loop(next))
      case Done => Stream.empty
    }
  }
  loop(() => body).iterator
}
```

The trampoline uses an internal loop that turns the sequence of `Iteration` objects into a `Stream`.
We then get an `Iterator` by calling `iterator` on the resulting stream object.
By using a `Stream` our evaluation is lazy; we don't evaluate our next iteration until it is needed.

The trampoline can be used to build an iterator directly.

```
val itr1 = trampoline {
  Yield(1, () => Yield(2, () => Yield(3, () => Done)))
}

for (i <- itr1) { println(i) }
```

That's pretty horrible to write, so let's use delimited continuations to create our `Iteration` objects automatically.

We use the `shift` and `reset` operators to break the computation up into `Iteration`s,
then use `trampoline` to turn the `Iteration`s into an `Iterator`.

```
import scala.continuations._
import scala.continuations.ControlContext.{shift,reset}

def iterator[R](body: => Unit @cps[Iteration[R],Iteration[R]]): Iterator[R] =
  trampoline {
    reset[Iteration[R],Iteration[R]] { body ; Done }
  }

def yld[R](result: R): Unit @cps[Iteration[R],Iteration[R]] =
  shift((k: Unit => Iteration[R]) => Yield(result, () => k(())))
```

Now we can rewrite our example.

```
val itr2 = iterator[Int] {
  yld(1)
  yld(2)
  yld(3)
}

for (i <- itr2) { println(i) }
```

Much better!

Now here's an example from the [C# reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) for `yield` that shows some more advanced usage.
The types can be a bit tricky to get used to, but it all works.

```
def power(number: Int, exponent: Int): Iterator[Int] = iterator[Int] {
  def loop(result: Int, counter: Int): Unit @cps[Iteration[Int],Iteration[Int]] = {
    if (counter < exponent) {
      yld(result)
      loop(result * number, counter + 1)
    }
  }
  loop(number, 0)
}

for (i <- power(2, 8)) { println(i) }
```

Comment: I'd like to see the output of scalac -print for iterator, yld, and the assignment to itr2. Could someone with the plugin add this to the answer?

Comment: I was just trying to apply this so I had the code running and handy. See http://gist.github.com/297230 for the output (scroll to the bottom).

Comment: I'd rename `iterator` to `yldIterator` or something like that, to avoid confusion. :-)

Comment: I just saw that this was adapted into the [grizzled scala](http://software.clapper.org/grizzled-scala/api/#grizzled.generator$) library.

Comment: Grizzled removed generators in 1.1.6 as it relied "on the unsupported and unmaintained Scala continuations plugin."
read here: https://github.com/bmc/grizzled-scala/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 5):

I managed to discover a way to do this, after a few more hours of playing around. I thought this was simpler to wrap my head around than all the other solutions I've seen thus far, though I did afterward very much appreciate Rich's and [Miles'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137619/scala-equivalent-to-python-generators/2146456#2146456) solutions.

```
def loopWhile(cond: =>Boolean)(body: =>(Unit @suspendable)): Unit @suspendable = {
  if (cond) {
    body
    loopWhile(cond)(body)
  }
}

  class Gen {
    var prodCont: Unit => Unit = { x: Unit => prod }
    var nextVal = 0
    def yld(i: Int) = shift { k: (Unit => Unit) => nextVal = i; prodCont = k }
    def next = { prodCont(); nextVal }
    def prod = {
      reset {
        // following is generator logic; can be refactored out generically
        var i = 0
        i += 1
        yld(i)
        i += 1
        yld(i)
        // scala continuations plugin can't handle while loops, so need own construct
        loopWhile (true) {
          i += 1
          yld(i)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  val it = new Gen
  println(it.next)
  println(it.next)
  println(it.next)
```

Comment: Scala continuations can't handle while loops? Ouch!

Comment: Indeed. :( Hopefully that one's a work-in-progress, but I believe for-comprehensions are definitely not compatible with shift, as that would imply ripping apart the map/foreach/etc.

Comment: Not any longer. Calling cps code from within the while loop is possible for some time already. For-comprehensions are still unsupported though (I don't really think they'll gain support ever)

Comment: @PrzemekPokrywka: ...unless Scala gets her own VM, or Java 12 is released, or something.