# Scala implementation of C#-like yield with "for"

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, yield, continuations, yield-return

I'm trying to use various Scala implementations of C#-like yield return (i.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201882/implementing-yield-yield-return-using-scala-continuations/2215182)) with "for" -constructions such as:

```
private def permutations[T](s: Vector[T]) = {
  def swap(i: Int, j: Int) {
    val tmp = s(i)
    s.set(i, s.get(j))
    s.set(j, tmp)
  }

  iterator[Vector[T]] {
    def generate(left: Int, right: Int): Unit @cps[Iteration[Vector[T]]] = {
      if (left >= right)
        yieldValue(s)

      else {
        generate(left, right)
        for (i <- left to right) {
          swap(left, i)
          generate(left+1, right)
          swap(left, i)
        }
      }
    }

    generate(0, s.size-1)
  } 
}
```

But this code compiles with error:

```
error: no type parameters for method foreach: (f: (Int) => U)Unit exist so that it can be applied to arguments ((Int) => Unit @util.continuations.package.cps[ru.ispras.texterra.nlp.GHMMDisambiguator.Iteration[Vector[T]]])
--- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
found   : (Int) => Unit @util.continuations.package.cps[ru.ispras.texterra.nlp.GHMMDisambiguator.Iteration[Vector[T]]]
required: (Int) => ?U
for (i <- left to right) {
```

As I understand I have to make all code inside for to be type of `() => Unit`, not of `() => Unit @with-annotations`. How can I do that?

This problem seems to be very common, but I didn't found any mentions in the Internet.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the braces on that example don't seem to match up.  And how are you able to call generate there? It's in a nested scope.

Comment: I solved both problems by removing an extra brace.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the following, which provides an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934226/continuations-and-for-comprehensions-whats-the-incompatibility

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `iterator` type from the linked example, is it possible that your `generate` method needs to have the following return type rather than the one you have there?

```
Unit @cps[Iteration[Vector[T]],Iteration[Vector[T]]]
```

I'm afraid I haven't got much experience with this stuff but it looks a lot like the methods you call within `iterator` must have two (identical) type arguments on the annotation.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/util/continuations/package.html : 

    type cps = cpsParam[A, A] 

So I think scala team had renamed cps to cpsParam and added type cps
Even if I use @cps[Iteration[Vector[T]],Iteration[Vector[T]]] the problem remains

Comment: Oh well, sorry! I was just working from what I saw there. Good luck getting it working!