# What is the preferred way to implement 'yield' in Scala?

Tags: python, scala, generator, yield, text-processing

I am doing writing code for PhD research and starting to use Scala.  I often have to do text processing. I am used to Python, whose 'yield' statement is extremely useful for implementing complex iterators over large, often irregularly structured text files.  Similar constructs exist in other languages (e.g. C#), for good reason.

Yes I know there have been previous threads on this.  But they look like hacked-up (or at least badly explained) solutions that don't clearly work well and often have unclear limitations. I would like to write code something like this:

```
import generator._

def yield_values(file:String) = {
  generate {
    for (x <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines()) {
      # Scala is already using the 'yield' keyword.
      give("something")
      for (field <- ":".r.split(x)) {
        if (field contains "/") {
          for (subfield <- "/".r.split(field)) { give(subfield) }
        } else {
          // Scala has no 'continue'.  IMO that should be considered
          // a bug in Scala.
          // Preferred: if (field.startsWith("#")) continue
          // Actual: Need to indent all following code
          if (!field.startsWith("#")) {
            val some_calculation = { ... do some more stuff here ... }
            if (some_calculation && field.startsWith("r")) {
              give("r")
              give(field.slice(1))
            } else {
              // Typically there will be a good deal more code here to handle different cases
              give(field)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to see the code that implements generate() and give().  BTW give() should be named yield() but Scala has taken that keyword already.

I gather that, for reasons I don't understand, Scala continuations may not work inside a for statement.  If so, generate() should supply an equivalent function that works as close as possible to a for statement, because iterator code with yield almost inevitably sits inside a for loop.

Please, I would prefer not to get any of the following answers:

1. 'yield' sucks, continuations are better. (Yes, in general you can do more with continuations.  But they are hella hard to understand, and 99% of the time an iterator is all you want or need.  If Scala provides lots of powerful tools but they're too hard to use in practice, the language won't succeed.)
2. This is a duplicate. (Please see my comments above.)
3. You should rewrite your code using streams, continuations, recursion, etc. etc. (Please see #1.  I will also add, technically you don't need for loops either.  For that matter, technically you can do absolutely everything you ever need using [SKI combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus).)
4. Your function is too long.  Break it up into smaller pieces and you won't need 'yield'. You'd have to do this in production code, anyway. (First, "you won't need 'yield'" is doubtful in any case.  Second, this isn't production code.  Third, for text processing like this, very often, breaking the function into smaller pieces -- especially when the language **forces** you to do this because it lacks the useful constructs -- only makes the code *harder* to understand.)
5. Rewrite your code with a function passed in. (Technically, yes you can do this.  But the result is no longer an iterator, and chaining iterators is much nicer than chaining functions.  In general, a language should not force me to write in an unnatural style -- certainly, the Scala creators believe this in general, since they provide shitloads of syntactic sugar.)
6. Rewrite your code in this, that, or the other way, or some other cool, awesome way I just thought of.

Comment: Nice question. It seems like continuations would be the natural way to implement this. Is it true that Scala's delimited continuations are incompatible with `for` comprehensions (I mean, the higher-order methods like `foreach` that are defined on common collections)? It would be great if someone could explain clearly the limitations of Scala's continuations.

Comment: -1 Rejecting "Rewrite your code in this way." answers in general is a poor attitude and in particular not very clever.

Comment: And somehow your code looks like a parser. Have you considered using parser combinators?

Comment: Looks like your "attitude" just got you 3 downvotes, but I tend to agree.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The premise of your question seems to be that you want exactly Python's yield, and you don't want any other reasonable suggestions to do the same thing in a different way in Scala.  If this is true, and it is that important to you, why not use Python?  It's quite a nice language.  Unless your Ph.D. is in computer science and using Scala is an important part of your dissertation, if you're already familiar with Python and really like some of its features and design choices, why not use it instead?

Anyway, if you actually want to learn how to solve your problem in Scala, it turns out that for the code you have, delimited continuations are overkill.  All you need are flatMapped iterators.

Here's how you do it.

```
// You want to write
for (x <- xs) { /* complex yield in here */ }
// Instead you write
xs.iterator.flatMap { /* Produce iterators in here */ }

// You want to write
yield(a)
yield(b)
// Instead you write
Iterator(a,b)

// You want to write
yield(a)
/* complex set of yields in here */
// Instead you write
Iterator(a) ++ /* produce complex iterator here */
```

That's it!  All your cases can be reduced to one of these three.

In your case, your example would look something like

```
Source.fromFile(file).getLines().flatMap(x =>
  Iterator("something") ++
  ":".r.split(x).iterator.flatMap(field =>
    if (field contains "/") "/".r.split(field).iterator
    else {
      if (!field.startsWith("#")) {
        /* vals, whatever */
        if (some_calculation && field.startsWith("r")) Iterator("r",field.slice(1))
        else Iterator(field)
      }
      else Iterator.empty
    }
  )
)
```

P.S. Scala *does* have continue; it's done like so (implemented by throwing stackless (light-weight) exceptions):

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
for (blah) { breakable { ... break ... } }
```

but that won't get you what you want because Scala doesn't have the yield you want.

Comment: That continue works if you have one generator, or if you only want to continue to the innermost generator. Personally, I think it is so crippled that it isn't worth even mentioning its existence.

Comment: @Danial C. Sobral - You can create your own breakables so you can break out of whatever you want wherever you want.  It doesn't play so nicely with creating iterators, however, but for pure control flow it's actually more flexible than most languages' break/continue.

Answer (score 17):

> 'yield' sucks, continuations are better

Actually, Python's `yield` *is* a continuation.

What is a continuation? A continuation is saving the present point of execution with all its state, such that one can *continue* at that point later. That's precisely what Python's `yield`, and, also, precisely how it is implemented.

It is my understanding that Python's continuations are not *delimited*, however. I don't know much about that -- I might be wrong, in fact. Nor do I know what the implications of that may be.

Scala's continuation do not work at run-time -- in fact, there's a continuations library for Java that work by doing stuff to bytecode at run-time, which is free of the constrains that Scala's continuation have.

Scala's continuation are entirely done at compile time, which require quite a bit of work. It also requires that the code that will be "continued" be prepared by the compiler to do so.

And that's why for-comprehensions do not work. A statement like this:

```
for { x <- xs } proc(x)
```

If translated into

```
xs.foreach(x => proc(x))
```

Where `foreach` is a method on `xs`'s class. Unfortunately, `xs` class has been long compiled, so it cannot be modified into supporting the continuation. As a side note, that's also why Scala doesn't have `continue`.

Aside from that, yes, this is a duplicate question, and, yes, you should find a different way to write your code.

Comment: There are continuation based solutions that do what Urban Vagabond wants (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201882/implementing-yield-yield-return-using-scala-continuations/2218589#2218589 ), except they apparently don't work with `foreach` defined on existing collections. The trivial solution is to rewrite the for loops to while loops. But alternatively, could one replace existing `foreach` methods with custom methods that *are* compatible with continuations?

Comment: Tiark (the Scala continuations guy) has a *really* awesome trick that makes almost every higher-order function in the collections library continuations-compatible (including `foreach`).  However, a) it hasn't landed yet, and b) it's not a general solution for any higher-order function (it only works because the collections library is insanely generic).

Comment: Do you have a link? Any estimated time when this will be merged into trunk?

Comment: @Daniel That's really a trick I'd like to see. From what you said, it seems it has something to do with CBF?

Comment: @soc, Here's one attempt at making higher order functions that are compatible with Scala's continuations: [Monadic Continuations in Scala](http://www.earldouglas.com/monadic-continuations-in-scala/)

Comment: @KiptonBarros: broken link.
But I found this one: https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/funtinuations

Answer (score 8):

The implementation below provides a Python-like generator.

Notice that there's a function called `_yield` in the code below, because `yield` is already a keyword in Scala, which by the way, does not have anything to do with `yield` you know from Python.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream
import scala.util.continuations._

object Generators {
  sealed trait Trampoline[+T]

  case object Done extends Trampoline[Nothing]
  case class Continue[T](result: T, next: Unit => Trampoline[T]) extends Trampoline[T]

  class Generator[T](var cont: Unit => Trampoline[T]) extends Iterator[T] {
    def next: T = {
      cont() match {
        case Continue(r, nextCont) => cont = nextCont; r
        case _ => sys.error("Generator exhausted")
      }
    }

    def hasNext = cont() != Done
  }

  type Gen[T] = cps[Trampoline[T]]

  def generator[T](body: => Unit @Gen[T]): Generator[T] = {
    new Generator((Unit) => reset { body; Done })
  }

  def _yield[T](t: T): Unit @Gen[T] =
    shift { (cont: Unit => Trampoline[T]) => Continue(t, cont) }
}


object TestCase {
  import Generators._

  def sectors = generator {
    def tailrec(seq: Seq[String]): Unit @Gen[String] = {
      if (!seq.isEmpty) {
        _yield(seq.head)
        tailrec(seq.tail)
      }
    }

    val list: Seq[String] = List("Financials", "Materials", "Technology", "Utilities")
    tailrec(list)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for (s <- sectors) { println(s) }
  }
}
```

It works pretty well, including for the typical usage of for loops.

Caveat: we need to remember that Python and Scala differ in the way continuations are implemented. Below we see how generators are typically used in Python and compare to the way we have to use them in Scala. Then, we will see why it needs to be like so in Scala.

If you are used to writing code in Python, you've probably used generators like this:

```
// This is Scala code that does not compile :(
// This code naively tries to mimic the way generators are used in Python

def myGenerator = generator {
  val list: Seq[String] = List("Financials", "Materials", "Technology", "Utilities")
  list foreach {s => _yield(s)}
}
```

This code above does not compile. Skipping all convoluted theoretical aspects, the explanation is: it fails to compile because *"the type of the for loop"* does not match the type involved as part of the continuation. I'm afraid this explanation is a complete failure. Let me try again:

If you had coded something like shown below, it would compile fine:

```
def myGenerator = generator {
  _yield("Financials")
  _yield("Materials")
  _yield("Technology")
  _yield("Utilities")
}
```

This code compiles because the generator can be *decomposed* in a sequence of `yield`s and, in this case, a `yield` matches the type involved in the continuation. To be more precise, the code can be decomposed onto chained blocks, where each block ends with a `yield`. Just for the sake of clarification, we can think that the sequence of `yield`s could be expressed like this:

```
{ some code here; _yield("Financials")
    { some other code here; _yield("Materials")
        { eventually even some more code here; _yield("Technology")
            { ok, fine, youve got the idea, right?; _yield("Utilities") }}}}
```

Again, without going deep into convoluted theory, the point is that, after a `yield` you need to provide another block that ends with a `yield`, or close the chain otherwise. This is what we are doing in the pseudo-code above: after the `yield` we are opening another block which in turn ends with a `yield` followed by another `yield` which in turn ends with another `yield`, and so on. Obviously this thing must end at some point. Then the only thing we are allowed to do is closing the entire chain.

OK. But... how we can `yield` multiple pieces of information? The answer is a little obscure but makes a lot of sense after you know the answer: we need to employ tail recursion, and the the last statement of a block must be a `yield`.

```
  def myGenerator = generator {
    def tailrec(seq: Seq[String]): Unit @Gen[String] = {
      if (!seq.isEmpty) {
        _yield(seq.head)
        tailrec(seq.tail)
      }
    }

    val list = List("Financials", "Materials", "Technology", "Utilities")
    tailrec(list)
  }
```

Let's analyze what's going on here:

1. Our generator function `myGenerator` contains some logic that obtains that generates information. In this example, we simply use a sequence of strings.
2. Our generator function `myGenerator` calls a recursive function which is responsible for `yield`-ing multiple pieces of information, obtained from our sequence of strings.
3. The recursive function **must be declared before use**, otherwise the compiler crashes.
4. The recursive function `tailrec` provides the tail recursion we need.

The rule of thumb here is simple: substitute a for loop with a recursive function, as demonstrated above.

Notice that `tailrec` is just a convenient name we found, for the sake of clarification. In particular, `tailrec` does not need to be the last statement of our generator function; not necessarily. The only restriction is that you have to provide a sequence of blocks which match the type of an `yield`, like shown below:

```
  def myGenerator = generator {

    def tailrec(seq: Seq[String]): Unit @Gen[String] = {
      if (!seq.isEmpty) {
        _yield(seq.head)
        tailrec(seq.tail)
      }
    }

    _yield("Before the first call")
    _yield("OK... not yet...")
    _yield("Ready... steady... go")

    val list = List("Financials", "Materials", "Technology", "Utilities")
    tailrec(list)

    _yield("done")
    _yield("long life and prosperity")
  }
```

One step further, you must be imagining how real life applications look like, in particular if you are employing several generators. It would be a good idea if you find a way to *standardize* your generators around a single pattern that demonstrates to be convenient for most circumstances.

Let's examine the example below. We have three generators: `sectors`, `industries` and `companies`. For brevity, only `sectors` is completely shown. This generator employs a `tailrec` function as demonstrated already above. The trick here is that the same `tailrec` function is also employed by other generators. All we have to do is supply a different `body` function.

```
type GenP = (NodeSeq, NodeSeq, NodeSeq)
type GenR = immutable.Map[String, String]

def tailrec(p: GenP)(body: GenP => GenR): Unit @Gen[GenR] = {
  val (stats, rows, header)  = p
  if (!stats.isEmpty && !rows.isEmpty) {
    val heads: GenP = (stats.head, rows.head, header)
    val tails: GenP = (stats.tail, rows.tail, header)
    _yield(body(heads))
    // tail recursion
    tailrec(tails)(body)
  }
}

def sectors = generator[GenR] {
  def body(p: GenP): GenR = {
      // unpack arguments
      val stat, row, header = p
      // obtain name and url
      val name = (row \ "a").text
      val url  = (row \ "a" \ "@href").text
      // create map and populate fields: name and url
      var m = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, String]
      m.put("name", name)
      m.put("url",  url)
      // populate other fields
      (header, stat).zipped.foreach { (k, v) => m.put(k.text, v.text) }
      // returns a map
      m
  }

  val root  : scala.xml.NodeSeq = cache.loadHTML5(urlSectors) // obtain entire page
  val header: scala.xml.NodeSeq = ... // code is omitted
  val stats : scala.xml.NodeSeq = ... // code is omitted
  val rows  : scala.xml.NodeSeq = ... // code is omitted
  // tail recursion
  tailrec((stats, rows, header))(body)
} 

def industries(sector: String) = generator[GenR] {
  def body(p: GenP): GenR = {
      //++ similar to 'body' demonstrated in "sectors"
      // returns a map
      m
  }

  //++ obtain NodeSeq variables, like demonstrated in "sectors" 
  // tail recursion
  tailrec((stats, rows, header))(body)
} 

def companies(sector: String) = generator[GenR] {
  def body(p: GenP): GenR = {
      //++ similar to 'body' demonstrated in "sectors"
      // returns a map
      m
  }

  //++ obtain NodeSeq variables, like demonstrated in "sectors" 
  // tail recursion
  tailrec((stats, rows, header))(body)
}
```

- Credits to Rich Dougherty and huynhjl.
  See this SO thread: [Implementing yield (yield return) using Scala continuations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201882/implementing-yield-yield-return-using-scala-continuations)*
- Credits to Miles Sabin, for putting some of the code above together
  http://github.com/milessabin/scala-cont-jvm-coro-talk/blob/master/src/continuations/Generators.scala

Comment: Am i correct that this doesn't work with stuff like `for(){}` loops, since `shift{}` within them cause problems?

Comment: Hello Richard, this is what I'm looking for, more than the previous answers.  However, as mentioned by Li Haoyi, does this play nice with other parts of Scala?  It's no good if it doesn't work inside of for loops.

Comment: @UrbanVagabond : for loops need to be replaced by a recursive function which yields a given result type. I've rewritten the answer and I hope it is clear enough now.