# How do I group items T from an iterator into an Iterator[Seq[T]]

Tags: scala, iterator

For example, consider a small file.

```
one
two
three

four
five

six
seven
eight
nine
```

I would like to write code that would take a line iterator `it: Iterator[String]` and make an iterator `sectionIt: Iterator[Seq[String]]` that iterates over the sections.

In C# and Ruby this is easily accomplished with the yield keyword.  There's [talk of how to add that keyword to scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655738/does-scala-have-an-equivalent-to-c-sharp-yield), but it depends on compiler plugins.

One way to create `sectionIt` would be to create an `Iterator[Seq[String]]` directly and override `next` and `hasNext`.  This approach seems tedious and state-intensive for a higher-level language like Scala.

I realize there are other abstractions for streaming data, such as Iteratees, which may make this easier, but that's not an easy sell to someone who is learning a new language.

What is a good approach to writing the above code in Scala?

Comment: Why do you want these specific types? Why not `Seq[Seq[String]]`?

Comment: I don't want everything in memory at once.

Comment: I know you said "no iteratees", but do consider giving [Scalaz Stream](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream) a try! It doesn't get much better than `io.linesR("data.txt").split(_.isEmpty)`.

Comment: @TravisBrown, that's amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different version of the other answer:

```
  def section(it: Iterator[String]): Iterator[Seq[String]] = { 
    def spanned(it: Iterator[String]): Stream[Seq[String]] =
      if (!it.hasNext) Stream.empty
      else { val (a, b) = it span (_ != "") ; a.toSeq #:: spanned(b drop 1) }
    spanned(it).iterator
  }
```

It's a bit lazier and the behavior around reading between the blank lines is different:

```
scala> lazysplit.Test.splitOnBlankLines(f"%n%n%n%n%n".lines).size
res0: Int = 6

scala> lazysplit.Test.section(f"%n%n%n%n%n".lines).size
res1: Int = 5
```

Comment: Awesome. Using span makes a lot of sense for this problem. I had been missing that could construct iterators using streams.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish most of what you would want with Ruby or C#'s `yield` using `Stream`:

```
def splitOnBlankLines(iter: Iterator[String]): Iterator[Seq[String]] = {
  def asStream(list: List[String]): Stream[List[String]] = {
    if (iter.hasNext) {
      val line = iter.next()
      if (line == "")
        list.reverse #:: asStream(Nil)
      else
        asStream(line :: list)
    } else {
      list.reverse #:: Stream.empty
    }
  }
  asStream(Nil).iterator
}
```

Whenever we would want to `yield`, we use `#::` with the value we want to return (`list.reverse` in this case) and an expression representing the rest of the stream. `#::` takes this expression as a by-name parameter, so it doesn't execute until the rest of the `Stream` is needed. When returning the last value, we use `Stream.empty` to signify that no more values will be produced.

It's possible to combine this behavior of `Stream` with the continuations plugin to get something syntactically equivalent to Ruby or C#'s `yield` (in all of twenty lines of code), but the continuations plugin is not likely to ever become stable.

However, manually writing an `Iterator` is almost as simple:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

class BlankLineSplittingIterator(iter: Iterator[String]) extends Iterator[Seq[String]] {
  def hasNext = iter.hasNext
  def next = {
    if (!iter.hasNext)
      Iterator.empty.next
    @tailrec def untilBlank(list: List[String]): List[String] = {
      val line = iter.next()
      if (line == "" || !iter.hasNext)
        list.reverse
      else
        untilBlank(line :: list)
    }
    untilBlank(Nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: Will your stream code persist the entire data structure in memory when the iterator is traversed?

Comment: No. The returned `Iterator` only keeps a reference to the part of the `Stream` it has not yet returned.