# Is there a ruby equivalent to the Scala Option?

Tags: ruby, scala, scala-option

How do I model an optional value in ruby? Scala has Option[], which is what I'm looking for in ruby.

Comment: Rumonade gem has a scala-like Option for ruby: https://github.com/ms-ati/rumonade

Comment: You could also check the monadic gem which implements the Maybe monad, which is the equivalent of the Scala's Option - https://github.com/pzol/monadic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no equivalent in the standard library. You have to define your own. See [this article](http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/01/monads-in-ruby-with-nice-syntax.html).

Comment: That's what I feared. Defining your own works well, but using a library/bulitin is mostly easier. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't need it though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839697/why-is-the-use-of-maybe-option-not-so-pervasive-in-clojure

Comment: @OscarRyz: I agree that the types are a key aspect in higher order programming, but it is perfectly possible and plausible to do higher order programming without types. Types are not a _mandatory_ element here. Monads are relevant in both static as well as dynamic languages (See Clojure's minikanren for an excellent example). Option is a monad. Apart from providing a better type safety, it has several benefits, such as cutting down on the boilerplate, and at the same time providing an assurance that all possible cases have been dealt with. [..]

Comment: @OscarRyz: [..] These benefits could be exploited in dynamic languages too. Furthermore OP didn't ask whether or not `Option` should be used in Ruby. I pointed him to what he asked for. Ergo I do not feel your downvote is quite justified.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a Ruby expert, but I don't think there is an Option equivalent. As Ruby is object oriented, nothing stops you from writing your own implementation, but it won't be as useful as in a statically typed language, where the compiler *forces* you to do a proper check for the empty option, which is one of the main points for using this construct. Of course there are other advantages, like the possibility to chain Option values in several ways.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the [Rumonade](https://github.com/ms-ati/rumonade) gem? It gives you an Option class modeled on scala.

```
require 'rumonade'

[nil, 1, 123].map { |v| Option(v) }
=> [None, #<Rumonade::Some:0x7f2589297768 @value=1>, #<Rumonade::Some:0x7f2589297740 @value=123>]

[nil, 1, 123].map { |v| Option(v).map { |n| n.to_s }.select { |s| s.size > 2 } }.flatten
=> ["123"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of a `Maybe` class in nkpart's [adt library](https://github.com/nkpart/adt) under `examples/common_adts.rb`. There are also other example ADTs and the library makes it easier to define your own.

Answer (score 0):

I have just pushed a gem called [nil_be_gone](https://github.com/JanBussieck/nil_be_gone) that gives you an Optional that you can wrap objects with. It implements method_missing to check whether the value of the Optional is nil and if so simply return another Optional wrapped nil value, otherwise it calls the method on the object and wraps it again.

nil_be_gone implements `bind` as `and_then` which allows you to chain operations on Optional types, it's return methods which retrieves the value from Optional is value and the unit operation which wraps an object in the monad is defined by `self.from_value`.

Answer (score -8):

I don't know Scala, so I can't assert that's your answer:

In ruby, when you call a method, you can define a default value for a param:

```
def foo(i_am_mandatory, i_am_optionnal = :banga)
  puts i_am_optionnal
end

foo(:pouet, :plip)
=> :plip
foo(:pouet)
=> :banga
```

In that example, you can omit i_am_optionnal, which has a default value.

HTH.

Comment: That's not quite what `Option` monad is for.

Comment: That was the risk… Thank you to precise it :)