# Scala Option - Getting rid of if (opt.isDefined) {}

Tags: scala, scala-option

My code is becoming littered with the following code pattern:

```
val opt = somethingReturningAnOpt
if (opt.isDefinedAt) {
    val actualThingIWant = opt.get
}
```

Is there some way to simplify this? (it seems needlessly complex and a code smell). Ideally it would be something like:

```
if (Some(actualThingIWant) = somethingReturningAnOpt) {
   doSomethingWith(actualThingIWant)
}
```

Is anything like that possible?

Comment: That looks awfully close to `match` trying to use `if` syntax... any grudge against the former? Also, don't forget that Option is usable in `for` as well...

Comment: [This old thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079170/why-optiont) may be of some help.

Comment: The for syntax looks almost perfect - but my only qualm is that it is unintuitive and may give the impression to someone else on the codebase that it is looping over something rather than performing a conditional operation.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
somethingReturningAnOpt match {
  case Some(actualThingIWant) => doSomethingWith(actualThingIWant)
  case None =>
}
```

or as pst suggests:

```
somethingReturningAnOpt.foreach { actualThingIWant =>
  doSomethingWith(actualThingIWant)
}

// or...

for (actualThingIWant <- somethingReturningAnOpt) {
  doSomethingWith(actualThingIWant)
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the for syntax allows to easily chain and compose option call: val optRes = for { res1 <- getOptRes1 ; res2 <- getOptRes2 } yield { doSomething(res1,res2) } /* here, res1 and res2 are not option, but the content, if available, and optRes will be an Option[TypeOfDoSomethingReturn] */

Answer (score 33):

The [canonical guide](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/) to Option wrangling is by Tony Morris.

Comment: Personally I find case statements to be clearer for most situations; I'm not sure why Tony discourages them.

Comment: I happen to agree with both comments!

Comment: This looks like a link only answer. Can you quote from the article, to make it more useful (and bring it up todays site standard)?

Comment: Frankly, no. But if you want to add value to the world by paraphrasing someone else’s content just so that other people don’t have to click a link, please fill yer boots.

Answer (score 10):

Or:

```
somethingReturningAnOpt.map(doSomethingWith(_))
```

As in in:

```
val str = Some("foo")
str.map(_.toUpperCase)
```

... and use `flatMap` when the result of `doSomethingWith` is an Option itself.

```
val index = Option(Map("foo" -> "bar"))
index.flatMap(_.get("whatever"))        // Returns None :-)
index.map(_.get("whatever"))            // Returns Some(None) :-(
```

Comment: You could even shorten that to `somethingReturningAnOpt.map(doSomethingWith)`, no?

Comment: I think this is the correct way to use Option monad

Comment: This can only be used if the operation to execute for Some actually returns a value.

Answer (score 5):

The following code cannot do something useful, since after the `if`, `actualThingIWant` is not always defined and as such this code will not compile, as long as you try to use `actualThingIWant` later.

```
val opt = somethingReturningAnOpt
if (opt.isDefinedAt) {
    val actualThingIWant = opt.get
}
```

So, you have to provide a default value. This can be achieved with `getOrElse`:

```
val thingIWant = opt.getOrElse(myDefaultValue)
```

Or if you don't want to have `actualThingIWant` after the body of the `if`, which means you want to trigger some side-effects only if the option is defined, you can write:

```
opt.foreach{ thingIWant => 
  println(thingIWant)
}
```

or a bit shorter

```
opt.foreach(println)
```