# Scala error indicating val not member of model object although it is?

Tags: scala

**Summary:** I am pulling a list of user IDs from a members transaction table that is then used to generate a list of users from the database. This is then used to generate JSON sent to a page that lists users associated with an account.

**Background:** Scala code using Squeryl on Play! Framework

**The Error:** `value id is not a member of Option[models.User]` when mapping the users to the JSON generator

**The Code:** Here's code being used in succession to finally generate the JSON

```
def memberIds(accountId: Long) = { from(DB.members)(m =>
      where(m.accountId === accountId)
        select (m)).map(_.userId).toSet
  }

def membersToAccount(id: Long) = {
    memberIds(id).map( i => models.User.get(i))
  }

def listMembers(accountId: Long) = {
    Json(generate(Account.membersToAccount(accountId)
      .map(user => Map(
      "id" -> user.id,
      "name" -> user.name,
      "username" -> user.username
    ))))
  }
```

**The Confusion:** the User class contains an id val that looks like `case class User(
  val id: Long, etc.` I'm confused as to why it would create this error. Is it a problem with syntax or where I am mapping the users? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's cause models.User is wrapped in [Option container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2079758/298389) (actually, that is monad). It's like trying to call method of User directly on List of users, like: `List(someUsers).id`

Basically that means, that this value can be either Some (non null wrapper) or Nothing (just like `null` but better).

Moreover, it is better not to use `get` on Options, consider link above for details.

Comment: LOL I posted my fix 9 seconds after your answer. However, I will accept yours because I appreciate the better technique and I'll fix the code after I read over Option a little more. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue. Each user object was wrapped in an option like Some(user). So to fix this, I had to use the `.get` method on each property.

```
def listMembers(accountId: Long) = {
    Json(generate(Account.membersToAccount(accountId)
      .map( user => Map(
      "id" -> user.get.id,
      "name" -> user.get.name,
      "username" -> user.get.emailAddress
    ))))
  }
```