# When to use Option

Tags: scala

I learn Scala for some time and can't clearly understand the usage of Option. It helps me to avoid null checks when I chain functions (according to [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html)). That's clear for me :)

Next I see that Option can be kind of indicator for developer that null value is possible here and it must be handled. Is it true? If yes should I use Option whereever it's possible? For example

```
class Racer {
    val car = new Car()
}
```

I have Racer class and I'm sure that car field can't be null (because it's constant and get a value when I create Racer instance). No need for Option here.

```
class Racer {
    var car = new Car()
}
```

Here I make it so that the car can change. And it's possible for someone to assign null to car. Should I use Option here? If yes I notice that all my class fields are candidates for Option. And my code looks like this

```
class Racer {
    var car: Option[Car] = None
    var currentRace: Option[Race] = None
    var team: Option[Team] = None
    ...
}
```

Does it look good? For me it seems kind of Option overusing.

```
def foo(): Result = {
    if( something )
        new Result()
    else
        null
}
```

I have a method which can return null. Should I return Option instead? Should I always do it if it's possible for method to return null?

Any thoughts about it would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

My question is similiar to [Why option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079170/why-optiont) but I think it's not the same. It's more about *when,* not *why.* :)

Comment: in addition to other answers try to read this http://simply.liftweb.net/index-7.2.html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should avoid `null` as much as possible in Scala. It really only exists for interoperability with Java. So, instead of `null`, use `Option` whenever it's possible that a function or method can return "no value", or when it's logically valid for a member variable to have "no value".

With regard to your `Racer` example: Is a `Racer` really valid if it doesn't have a `car`, `currentRace` and `team`? If not, then you shouldn't make those member variables options. Don't just make them options because it's theoretically possible to assign them to `null`; do it only if logically you consider it a valid `Racer` object if any of those member variables has no value.

In other words, it's best to pretend as if `null` doesn't exist. The use of `null` in Scala code is a code smell.

```
def foo(): Option[Result] = if (something) Some(new Result()) else None
```

Note that `Option` has many useful methods to work with.

```
val opt = foo()

// You can use pattern matching
opt match {
  case Some(result) => println("The result is: " + result)
  case None         => println("There was no result!")
}

// Or use for example foreach
opt foreach { result => println("The result is: " + result) }
```

Also, if you want to program in the functional style, you should avoid mutable data as much as possible, which means: avoid the use of `var`, use `val` instead, use immutable collections and make your own classes immutable as much as possible.

Comment: In addition to "pretend[ing] as if `null` doesn't exist", if you have to deal with Java code that gives you `foo` which might be `null`, you can use `Option(foo)`, which will turn `null` into `None`, and anything else into `Some(blah)`.

Answer (score 10):

When it comes to functional programming in Scala, `Option` is much preferable than `null` since it is type-safe and plays nice with other constructs in the functional paradigm.

Especially, you can easily write idiomatic code using high-order functions on `Option`. This [Scala Option Cheat Sheet](http://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/) is a helpful read on the topic.

Answer (score 8):

While `Option` can makes your class definition look verbose, the alternative is to not know when you need to test whether a variable is defined.  I think that in your example, if your class were immutable (all the fields were `val`s), you would not need so many `Option`s.

For your method `foo`, if you return null, you need to document it and the client needs to read that documentation.  Then the client will write a bunch of code like:

```
val result = foo(x)
if (result != null) {
  println(result)
}
```

If instead you define `foo` to return an `Option[Result]`, the type system forces the client to handle the possibility of an undefined result.  They also have the full power of the collections classes.

```
result foreach println
```

An additional advantage of using the collections method with an `Option` instead of testing for `null` is that if your method is extended to a multi-element collection (such as a `List`), you might not need to change your code at all.  For example, you might initially assume your `Racer` can only have a single crew, so you define `val crew: Option[Crew]` and you might test if the crew is older than 30 with `crew.forall(_.age > 30).getOrElse(false)`.  Now if you changed the definition to `val crew: List[Crew]` your old code would still compile and now you would check if all of your crew members are over 30.

Sometimes you need to deal with `null` because libraries you are using may return it.  For example, when you get a resource, you might get a `null` result.  Fortunately, it is easy to defensively wrap results so they are transformed into an option.

```
val resource = Option(this.getClass.getResource("foo"))
```

If `getResource` returned `null` then `resource` equals `None`, and otherwise it is a `Some[URL]`.  Cool!

Unfortunately, `Option` is likely to have some overhead because it involves an extra object creation.  However, that overhead is minimal compared to a null pointer exception!

Comment: To make a class immutable do you suggest to make a copy of an instance every time I want to change it? Like Nicolas told.

Comment: Yes, but this depends somewhat on how you are using the object.  If you have an object with many fields that you change frequently, immutable might not make sense.  However, you can often design your code differently so you are performing less mutation.  If you need mutation, you can hide the mutability through a trait (for example, List has a mutable field--you just can't access it).

Answer (score 6):

The idea behind `Options` is to get rid off `null`, so yes, you should use them instead of returning "`null` or a value". That's also why, if you want to model optional fields (0..1 relationship with other objects), using `Option` is definitely a good thing.

The little drawback is that it renders declaration of class with a lot of optional field a bit verbose, as you mentionned.

One more thing, in scala, you are encouraged to use "immutable objects", so in your example, the fields should be some `val`s. ;)

Comment: In case I use val how can I change the value? What if I want a new car for my racer?

Comment: The idea is to build a new object when a event like a new car occurs: `class Racer(name: String, car: Option[Car]) {def receiveANewCar(c: Car) = new Racer(name, Some(c)); def brokeHisCar = new Racer(name, None)}`