# Wrong forward reference with Null initialisation

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Quite often in Java we see algorithms like:

```
MyObject currentObject = null 

for(MyObject oldObject: objects){
    if(currentObject != null) doSomething
    else doSometing
    currentObject = oldObject  
}
```

I'm trying to implement this in **Scala**:

```
var currentObject: MyObject = null
for(oldObject <- objects){
    if(currentObject != null) doSomething
    else doSometing
    currentObject = oldObject  
}
```

However, I'm receiving a Wrong Forward reference compilation error.

I guess the problems is with the initialisation as null of the 
 currentObject?

UPDATED:

Here the actual code:

```
var protCoord:Coordinates     = new Coordinates()
var prevprotCoord:Coordinates = new Coordinates()
var coordMap = mutable.Map[Coordinates, GenomeCoordinates]()
var protein:EnsemblProteinEntry = null
var codingLength = 0

for (gtfEntry <- gtfEntries.toStream) {
  if (gtfEntry.isGene)
    mapping.addGene(new GTFGeneEntry(gtfEntry))
  if(gtfEntry.isTranscript){
    mapping.addTranscriptID(gtfEntry)
  if(protein != null) protein.multiMapCoordinates = coordMap // **I'm receiving the error here** 
    var protein = fastaEntries.getOrElse(gtfEntry.transcriptIdentifier, null)
  if(protein == null)
    protein = new EnsemblProteinEntry()
  protCoord = new Coordinates()
  prevprotCoord = new Coordinates()
  coordMap = mutable.Map[Coordinates, GenomeCoordinates]()
  codingLength = 0
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need more info. Code looks fine.

Comment: Note: Try to avoid using `null` in Scala - use `Option` (with its subtypes `Some` and `None`) instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698391/when-to-use-option

Comment: I suspect that if you do `for{ whatever <- ... } { theVar = whatever }` it will work, but against all this encoding.

Comment: Btw, Scala `for`s need to have a "right hand side", or something after then, either a straight expression (or block like `{...}`) or followed by `yield` with a expression or block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the loop you have `var protein` defined second time. The problem is that you try to use `protein` inside loop before it's defined.