# optional references types

Tags: c#, scala, null, nullable, scala-option

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why Option[T]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079170/why-optiont)

Reference types provide the special value `null` meaning "absence of a value". Value types have no such value, which is why C# introduced optional value types (along with special syntax for them).

Scala's `Option[T]` has three different "null" values: `null`, `None` and `Some(null)`. What exactly does this added complexity buy us in terms of safety and expressibility? When would I use which?

Comment: _"which is why C# introduced optional value types"_ It's not the reason.

Comment: This is one of the best explanations of why `Option` is better than `null`: [Why Scala's "Option" and Haskell's "Maybe" types will save you from null](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-scalas-and-haskells-types-will-save.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good Scala really only has one null value: `None`.  Don't use `null` (except for backward compatibility with existing Java code).

There are many answers on SO regarding why `Option[T]` is useful.  For example: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079170/why-optiont).

The short version:

It makes the optional nature a signature explicit.  The following clearly states that we expect that `t` could be "null":

```
def f(t: Option[T])
```

You don't have to null-check before operations: `(i: Option[Int]) => i.map(_ + 1)` works fine whether `i` is `Some(5)` or `None`, *and* preserves the `Option` wrapper to indicate that the input could have been `None` (and, thus, the output might be `None` as well).

```
def f(i: Option[Int]) = i.map(_ + 1)
f(Some(5)) // Some(6)
f(None)    // None
```

You can compose them easily with other `Option`s or collections:

```
val a: Option[Int] = Some(1)
val b: Option[Int] = Some(6)
val c: Option[Int] = Some(5)
val d: Option[Int] = None
for(x <- a; y <- b; z <- c) yield x + y + z // Some(12)
for(x <- a; y <- d; z <- c) yield x + y + z // None
```

Comment: I know it's going on three years since you posted your answer, but FYI, I'm getting the following in the Scala 2.11.4 REPL:

<console>:11: error: type mismatch;  found   : List[Int],  required: Option[?], for(x <- a; **y <- b**; z <- c) yield x + y + z

Comment: fixed; it now compiles.

Answer (score 1):

In C# (and in general in the .NET Framework) there is the type `Nullable<T>`, which is a kind of wrapper for value types.

```
Nullable<int> i = null;
if (i == null) ...
if (i.HasValue) { int k = i.Value; ... }
```

There is a shortcut for `Nullable<T>`: `T?`.

```
int? i = null;
```

---

On the other hand, there are optional parameters. You must define the default value of these. There is no way to know if they are missing.