# scala.Some cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: scala, casting, scalatra

In this application, I'm getting this error:

```
scala.Some cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

When trying this:

```
x.email.asInstanceOf[String]
```

x.email is an Option[String]

Edit: I understand that I'm dealing with different types here, I was just wondering if there were a more concise way to do nothing with None then a

```
match { case....}
```

sequence.  Because I am casting x.email into a String for JSON purposes, a null field will be handled by the JSON object, and I don't explicitly have to deal with it.  Sorry for being unclear!!

Comment: Simple answer is use the `foreach` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it's clear to you from the errors and types that `x.email` is not a `String`...

First, decide how you want to handle `None` (a valid option for something of type `Option[String]`).  You then have a number of options, including but not limited to:

```
x.email match {
case None => ...
case Some(value) => println(value) // value is of type String
}
```

---

Alternately, take a look at the `get` and `getOrElse` methods on `class Option`.

If you want to "degrade" the option to a String with a possible `null` value, then use

```
x.email.orNull // calls getOrElse(null)
```

---

Finally, if you just don't care about the `None` case (and want to ignore it), then just use a simple "for comprehension" which will "skip" the body in the `None` case:

```
for (value <- x.email) {
  // value is of type String
}
```

Comment: You'd probably use `orNull` instead of `getOrElse(null)`.

Comment: `orNull` doesn't always work. I just tried `java.lang.Integer` instead of `java.lang.String` and then compilation for `orNull` fails with `Cannot prove that Null <:< Int.`

Answer (score 4):

Casting isn't how you should be looking at conversions when it comes to Options. Have a look at the following REPL session:

```
C:\>scala -deprecation -unchecked 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated. Type :help for more information.

scala> val email:Option[String] = Some("x@y.com") 
email: Option[String] = Some(x@y.com)

scala> email.getOrElse("defaults@example.com") 
res0: String = x@y.com

scala>
```

You might also want to look at this SO question: [What is the point of the class Option[T]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079170/what-is-the-point-of-the-class-optiont)

and the Options API [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option)

Generally speaking, casting/coercion are kind-of taboo in FP world. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
x.map(_.toString).getOrElse("")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want use pattern matching:

```
x.email match {
  case Some(email) => // do something with email
  case None => // did not get the email, deal with it
}
```