# Why does this Scala for expression using tuples fail to compile?

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

With Scala 2.8.1, compiling this:

```
val t = (40, 2)

println(for ((i, j) <- List(t)) yield i + j)

val e: Either[String, (Int, Int)] = Right(t)
println(e.right.map {
  case (i, j) => i + j
})
println(for ((i, j) <- e.right) yield i + j)
```

gives this:

```
test.scala:9: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: Either[Nothing,(Int, Int)]
println(for ((i, j) <- e.right) yield i + j)
```

According to *Programming in Scala*, the for expression should be equivalent to the map/case expression, but only the latter compiles. What am I doing wrong, and how should I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, that is not *quite* the translation that is happening. You may refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/can-someone-explain-scalas-yield/1059501#1059501) for a more complete guide, but this case is not explicitly mentioned even there.

What happens is that a for comprehension with pattern matching filters the non-matching case. For example,

```
for((i, j) <- List((1, 2), 3)) yield (i, j)
```

will return `List((1, 2)): List[(Any, Any)]`, as `withFilter` is called first. Now, `Either` doesn't seem to have `withFilter`, so it will use `filter`, and here's the actual translation of that for comprehension:

```
e.right.filter { case (i, j) => true; case _ => false }.map { case (i, j) => i + j }
```

Which gives exactly the same error. The problem is that `e.right` returns a `RightProjection`, but `filter` on `RightProjection[A, B]` returns `Option[Either[Nothing, B]]`.

The reason for that is that there is no such thing as an "empty" `Either` (or `RightProjection`), so it needs to encapsulate its result on an `Option`.

Having said all that, it is truly surprising when looked at the for-comprehension level. I think the right thing would be for `filter` to return some kind of filtered projection instead.

Answer (score 2):

Right does not return the option you might expect, but a RightProjection. This fixes it:

```
println(for ((i, j) <- e.right.toOption) yield i + j)
```