# Concatenating sets contained within a set of objects, functionally in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm just beginning in scala and I'm converting some java code into scala and trying to make it nice and functionally elegant.

I have the following code containing a method (getRequiredUploadPathKeys) which gives a union of all of the path keys required by all of the available path templates in MyClass.

```
trait PathTemplate {
    def getRequiredPathKeys:Set[PathKey]
}

class MyClass(accessPaths:Set[PathTemplate], targetPath:PathTemplate){

    def getAllRequiredPathKeys: Set[PathKey] = {
        val pathKeys = HashSet[PathKey]()
        pathKeys.addAll(targetPath.getRequiredPathKeys)

        for (accessTemp <- accessPaths) {
            pathKeys.addAll(accessTemp.getRequiredPathKeys)
        }
        return pathKeys
    }
}
```

This method just seems like it could be much more concise in scala.  Can anyone point me towards how to get it there?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
def getAllRequiredPathKeys = (accessPaths map { _.getRequiredPathKeys }).flatten ++ targetPath.getRequiredPathKeys
```

Comment: You could use flatMap to make it even shorter.

Comment: Awesome thanks :)  I got pretty close to that, but the flatten method was the missing bit!

Answer (score 6):

```
def getAllRequiredPathKeys = 
  (accessPaths + targetPath).flatMap(_.getRequiredPathKeys)
```

Or with for

```
def getAllRequiredPathKeys = 
  for(path <- accessPaths + targetPath; 
      key <- path.getRequiredPathKeys) yield key
```

Answer (score 6):

The curious thing here is that you are using *Java's* `HashSet` -- there's no `addAll` in Scala -- and no need for that.

So I'm going to comment on various design decisions and how they differ from Java to Scala. First,

```
    val pathKeys = HashSet[PathKey]()
```

Idiomatic Scala doesn't usually refer to the class implementing the interface, since the interface has a factory. So you'd usually just use `Set[PathKey]()`. Also, this is obviously a Scala factory, since there's no `new` keyword -- which means the rest of the code wouldn't work, as there's no `addAll` in Scala's `Set`.

```
    pathKeys.addAll(targetPath.getRequiredPathKeys)
```

Here you don't use `targetPath.getRequiredPathKeys` directly because Java's `Set` is mutable. The default Scala `Set` is immutable, which makes this useless -- you can just use `targetPath.getRequirePathKeys` as the base set, without having to add its elements to another collection.

Performance-wise, Scala -- like functional languages -- use *[persistent datastructures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure)* in its immutable collections implementations. That means it reuses parts of one data structure to create a derived data structure, instead of copying everything every time you create a new data structure. This is only possible because of the immutability guarantees.

At any rate, you could just do this:

```
val pathKeys = targetPath.getRequiredPathKeys
```

Next,

```
    for (accessTemp <- accessPaths) {
        pathKeys.addAll(accessTemp.getRequiredPathKeys)
    }
```

First, the idiomatic use of for comprehensions is to return a value, ie, for-yield. The above use should be restricted just to the side-effectful parts of your code. To be more clear, the above could be done in two steps:

```
    // Get all required Path Keys
    val requiredPathKeys = for {
        accessPath <- accessPaths
        requiredPathKey <- accessPath.getRequiredPathKeys
    } yield requiredPathKey

    // Then add them
    pathKeys.addAll(requiredPathKeys)
```

However, given that you don't `addAll` stuff to Scala's `Set`, you'd either need to make `pathKeys` a `var`, or use a mutable data structure, or simply change the order:

```
    val requiredPathKeys = for {
        accessPath <- accessPaths
        requiredPathKey <- accessPath.getRequiredPathKeys
    } yield requiredPathKey

    val pathKeys = targetPath.getRequiredPathKeys ++ requiredPathKeys
```

Notice, however, the repetition of `getRequiredPathKeys`. Functional programmers abhor repetition. Sometimes overly so, in my opinion, but, in this case, it can be easily removed:

```
    val pathKeys = for {
        accessPath <- accessPaths + targetPath
        requiredPathKey <- accessPath.getRequiredPathKeys
    } yield requiredPathKey
```

The above code suggests another improvement. If you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1052476/53013) about Scala's for comprehensions, you'll see that the above is equivalent to

```
    val pathKeys = (accessPaths + targetPath).flatMap( accessPath =>
        accessPath.getRequiredPathKeys.map( requiredPathKey => requiredPathKey ))
```

The `map` at the end is redundant, since it doesn't do anything. In fact, whenever a `yield` returns just a simple identifier, there's a redundant `map` in the expression. Removing it gives us:

```
    val pathKeys = (accessPaths + targetPath).flatMap(accessPath =>
        accessPath.getRequiredPathKeys)
```

Or, using Scala's anonymous function parameter syntax,

```
    val pathKeys = (accessPaths + targetPath).flatMap(_.getRequiredPathKeys)
```

Finally,

```
    return pathKeys
```

The keyword `return` in Scala is used to designate an exception in the work flow -- a point at which the method's execution is aborted instead of going through to the end. Not that this isn't without use, but, like exceptions themselves, it shouldn't be used without cause. Here, you should have used

```
    pathKeys
```

But, at this point, your code became just these two lines:

```
    val pathKeys = (accessPaths + targetPath).flatMap(_.getRequiredPathKeys)
    pathKeys
```

Which makes the `val` assignment completely redudant. You can thus reduce it to:

```
    (accessPaths + targetPath).flatMap(_.getRequiredPathKeys)
```

So the method becomes

```
def getAllRequiredPathKeys: Set[PathKey] = {
    (accessPaths + targetPath).flatMap(_.getRequiredPathKeys)
}
```

Now, I know I said "finally" back there, but there's one more tidbit of Scala convention to apply. Whenever a method contains a single expression instead of multiple statements, the convention is to ommit the curly braces. In other words, do this:

```
def getAllRequiredPathKeys: Set[PathKey] =
    (accessPaths + targetPath).flatMap(_.getRequiredPathKeys)
```

Or, if space allowed it, put everything on a single line. In fact, if you removed `getAllRequiredPathKeys` type, it would fit nicely. On the other hand, explicit return types on public method are encouraged.

So this will give you a Scala's immutable `Set`. Let's say your input and output must be Java's `Set`. In that case, I don't see anything that could be done to simplify your code, unless you were willing to convert between Java and Scala sets. You could do that like this:

```
trait PathTemplate {
    def getRequiredPathKeys:java.util.Set[PathKey]
}

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

class MyClass(accessPaths:java.util.Set[PathTemplate], targetPath:PathTemplate){
    def getAllRequiredPathKeys: java.util.Set[PathKey] =
        (accessPaths.asScala + targetPath).flatMap(_.getRequiredPathKeys.asScala).asJava
}
```

This, however, uses Scala's *mutable* `Set`, which means each operation creating a new `Set` will copy all the contents of the old `Set`.

Comment: Wow that's amazing.  I'm still digesting all of it, but it's a great description of the evolution of the solution.  Thankyou :)

Comment: That's a great walk-through, perfect for Java refugees! Thanks!