# Equivalent of Haskell do-notation or F# Computation Expressions in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, f#, monads, do-notation

F# Computation Expressions allow to hide the complexity of monadic syntax behind a thick layer of syntactic sugar. Is there something similar available in Scala?

I think it's for comprehensions ...

Example:

```
val f = for {
  a <- Future(10 / 2) // 10 / 2 = 5
  b <- Future(a + 1)  //  5 + 1 = 6
  c <- Future(a - 1)  //  5 - 1 = 4
 } yield b * c         //  6 * 4 = 24

 val result = f.get
```

But it doesn't really feel right. Is there a better syntax?

for exemple in haskell you would have

```
    main = do fromHandle <- getAndOpenFile "Copy from: " ReadMode
          toHandle   <- getAndOpenFile "Copy to: " WriteMode 
          contents   <- hGetContents fromHandle
          hPutStr toHandle contents
          hClose toHandle
          putStr "Done."
```

this unlike scala doesn't look like a  foreach loops.
Scala syntax seem to have too strong coupling with List comprehension which is a distinct concept. Which prevent me from writing internal DSL (monad) that doesn't look strange.

Comment: `for` comprehensions is exactly right. They desugar to `map` and `flatMap` behind the scenes, which is exactly how Haskell `do` notation works (except those methods are called `fmap` and `>>=` in Haskell).

Comment: @pelotom I'd love to see an answer that explains a bit more of that.

Comment: @Dan Burton - This question has been asked and answered several times... I'll refer you to this excellent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/can-someone-explain-scalas-yield/1059501#1059501

Comment: Correction to my first comment... `fmap` is actually not used in Haskell desugaring of `do`-notation, because there is no `yield` statement which necessitates it (and also we can't be sure all `Monad`s are `Functor`s, even though they should be)... instead of a keyword `yield` you just use the `return` function which, when called as the last statement in a `do` block, amounts to an `fmap`.

Comment: What is it about the notation that doesn't feel right?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: well he's quite right in that `for` is too strongly associated with looping; there's no way around it; extracting values from `Option`s reads quite awkward (especially to the untrained eye) using a `for`-loop like syntax, and I'm still not comfortable with it after a few months, especially when somebody else looks at the code who might not be a Scala expert.

Comment: @ErikAllik That's just a result of a limited experience in computer languages. It's funny that one says "for is associated with loops", when on a bunch of languages the keyword is `loop`, or `do`/`loop`, with no `for` in sight. So, I get and respect that one might feel this way, but the thing to do is get over it, in my opinion.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: I don't see how the following logical construction makes sense: "because some languages don't use `for` for looping, `for` should not be assumed to be associated with looping"

Comment: @ErikAllik It makes as much sense as _"because some languages use `for` for looping, `for` should be assumed to be associated with looping"_, so you don't have a leg to stand on. Regardless, that's not what I said. What I said is that this association is a result of limited exposure to programming languages -- being forced to drop unreasonable assumptions (`loop` is reasonably associated with loops, but `for`?) is a result of expanding your horizons, and Scala is as good a start as any for that.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: which other languages besides Scala use `for` for constructs other than looping?

Comment: @ErikAllik I have no clue, and that's not the point. The point is that there's nothing special about "for" to indicate loops, many other languages use `loop` for them, and that people learning more than a few closely related languages should be prepared to drop the conventions learned from those languages.

Comment: We can just keep arguing forever of course but it won't change the fact that for most people `for` associates with looping, and for a good reason. Yes, it's possible to "get over it", but that doesn't change the point really.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seem like there is no such syntax available in scala and we would need to implement it ourself using the compiler plugin architecture.

Comment: I've thought of using macros—have you considered that?

Answer (score 4):

The missing piece is probably the use of `=` is scala's for-comprehensions:

```
val f = for {
  a <- Future(10 / 2) // 10 / 2 = 5
  b <- Future(a + 1)  //  5 + 1 = 6
  c <- Future(a - 1)  //  5 - 1 = 4
  d = b * c           //  6 * 4 = 24
} yield d


val result = f.get
```

With judicious mixing of both `<-` and `=`, you should have all the flexibility you need.

Comment: Sometimes I wish Haskell's `do` syntax would infer `let` from the use of `=`