# Scala - Iterator over all the lines in the files in a directory

Tags: scala, io, lazy-evaluation

I really like the

```
for (line <- Source fromFile inputPath getLines) {doSomething line}
```

construction for iterating over a file in scala and am wondering if there is a way to use a similar construction for iterating over the lines in all the files in a directory.

An important restriction here is that all files add up to an amount of space that would generate a heap overflow.  (think dozens of GB, so increasing heap size isn't an option)  As a work around for the time being, I have been cat'ing every together into one file and using the above construction which works b/c of laziness.

Point being, this seems to raise questions like.. can I concatenate two (hundred) lazy iterators and get a really big, really lazy one?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, although it's not quite so concise:

```
import java.io.File
import scala.io.Source

for {
  file <- new File(dir).listFiles.toIterator if file.isFile
  line <- Source fromFile file getLines
} { doSomething line }
```

The trick is `flatMap` and [its `for`-comprehension syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/334519). The above, for example, is more or less equivalent to the following:

```
new File(dir)
  .listFiles.toIterator
  .filter(_.isFile)
  .flatMap(Source fromFile _ getLines)
  .map(doSomething)
```

As Daniel Sobral notes in a comment below, this approach (and the code in your question) will leave files open. If this is a one-off script or you're just working in the REPL, this might not be a big deal. If you do run into problems, you can use the [pimp-my-library pattern](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) to implement some basic resource management:

```
implicit def toClosingSource(source: Source) = new {
  val lines = source.getLines
  var stillOpen = true
  def getLinesAndClose = new Iterator[String] {
    def hasNext = stillOpen && lines.hasNext
    def next = {
      val line = lines.next
      if (!lines.hasNext) { source.close() ; stillOpen = false }
      line
    }
  }
}
```

Now just use `Source fromFile file getLinesAndClose` and you won't have to worry about files being left open.

Comment: That's perfect, I just ran over around 10gb of files using the scala repl with a code bit based on that and the memory usage barely budged.  Thanks much!

Comment: Note, however, that the `Source` for each file is not being closed. In this particular case, where code might touch hundreds of files, using some sort of ARM is important.