# Simple function to read lines from a file in Scala lazily using scala-arm

Tags: scala, memory, io, lazy-evaluation

I want to write a Scala function to read all of the lines from a file lazily (i.e returning an `Iterator[String]`) which also closes the file afterwards. I know about the idiom `io.Source.fromFile("something.txt").getLines` however as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097189/scala-iterator-over-all-the-lines-in-the-files-in-a-directory) this will not close the file afterwards. Surely there is a simple way to do this?

Currently I'm using this, with the [scala-arm library](http://jsuereth.com/scala-arm/):

```
import resource.managed
import io.{Source, BufferedSource}
def lines(filename: String): Iterator[String] = {
  val reader = managed(Source.fromFile(filename, "UTF-8"))
  reader.map(_.getLines).toTraversable.toIterator
}
```

but this seems to read the whole file into memory as far as I can tell.

I come from a Python background, where this is laughably trivial:

```
def lines(filename):
   with open(filename) as f:
       for line in f:
           yield line
```

Surely there is a reasonably straightforward Scala equivalent which I just haven't managed to work out yet.

Comment: Why do you think it reads the entire file into memory? `getLines` returns an `Iterator[String]`

Comment: Yep, `getLines` is lazy, like I want, but something that `scala-arm` is doing when it calls it is reading everything into memory -- when I run `println(lines("BIGFILE.txt").slice(1, 10).toList)` I get an `OutOfMemoryError`, while `println(Source.fromFile("BIGFILE.txt").getLines.slice(1, 10).toList)` runs without problems (although doesn't close the file afterwards apparently).

Comment: did you solve the issue?