# Is 'yield' in Scala equivalent to map function?

Tags: scala, haskell, dictionary, erlang, yield

I'm starting to study the Scala programming language.
I've some grasp of FP languages like Erlang and Haskell and I have a doubt about the meaning of the for/yield expression, like:

```
for (arg <- args) yield arg.length
```

This would collect an array with the lengths of any input argument.
From what I've understood this seems like the map function in normal FP programming:

```
map (\a -> a * 2) [1, 2, 3] (in Haskell)
```

I know that Scala library contains the scala.collection.map method, so I would like to know: is there any difference or limitation in using either style, or they are exactly the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone explain Scala's yield?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/can-someone-explain-scalas-yield)

Comment: Scala's for comprehension are similar to Haskell's `do` notation.

Comment: #Daniel, but I'm not asking for 'yield' meaning, but for similarities with other FP expressions!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`for ... yield` comprehension in Scala is translated by compiler to the `map`, `flatMap` and `withFilter` method calls. `for` without `yield` would be translated to the `foreach` method call. You can find some examples and more information here:

http://tataryn.net/2011/10/whats-in-a-scala-for-comprehension/

and here

http://adamwojtuniak.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/scala-for-comprehensions/

Comment: And so, flatMap and withFilter are equivalent to concat and select... They should really define a standard naming system for this functional patterns ;)

Comment: @tenshi, unfortunately, the first link you posted is no longer valid.

Answer (score 6):

Scala's `for`/`yield` expressions are completely equivalent to list/monad comprehensions in Haskell, and have exactly the same capabilities, as long as you stick to one type per `for` expression.  (I don't know about Erlang, though.)

In particular, your example exactly translates to `[length arg | arg <- args]`, translating the Scala method call `x.f` to the Haskell function application `f x`.

Comment: Does `yield` generate incremental output, or the whole list in one go?

Comment: Good example Ptharien, Haskell has been always ahead of time! About the yield incremental output, I think it matters when you want to parallelize code, for what I remember Scala has parallel collection and .par method for that in 2.9.

Answer (score 3):

The for-yield is compiled down to maps - it is in the Programming in Scala book.