# Explain how looping behaves in Scala compared to Java when accessing values

Tags: scala

In the following code :

```
val expression : String = "1+1";
     for (expressionChar <- expression) {
      println(expressionChar)
    }
```

the output is "1+1"

How is each character being accessed here ? What is going on behind the scenes in Scala. Using Java I would need to use the .charAt method , but not in Scala, why ?

Comment: As far as I remember, if there's no `yield`, the for-comprehension turns into `foreach`, so you're effectively doing `expression.foreach(println(_))`, or more verbose version: `expression.foreach(character => println(character))` (if there's a `yield`, then it's `flatMap`, right?) as string is a collection or, more precisely, a sequence of characters . I'm not 100% sure that's the exact mechanism though, so I'll wait for someone more oriented in the topic to chime in :)

Comment: The reason that you need to use `charAt` in Java, is that strings aren't iterable in Java, so you have to create an index variable and loop with that. If they were iterable, you could write `for(char expressionChar : expression)` (like you can with arrays of collections already) pretty much like in Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In scala, a for comprehension:

```
for (p <- e) dosomething
```

would be translated to

```
e.foreach { x => dosomething }
```

You can look into [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) 6.19 for more details.
However, `String` in scala is just a Java `String`, which doesnot have a method `foreach`.
But there is an implicit conversion defined in [Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24) which convert `String` to [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps) which indeed have a `foreach` method.

So, finally the code `for(x <- "abcdef") println(x)` be translated to:

```
Predef.augmentString("abcdef").foreach(x => println(x))
```

You can look int the scala reference or [Scala Views](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/130) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> for (c <- "1+1") println(c)
1
+
1
```

Is the same as

```
scala> "1+1" foreach (c => println(c))
1
+
1
```

Scalas for-comprehension is not a loop but a composition of higher order functions that operate on the input. The rules on how the for-comprehension is translated by the compiler can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/465304).

Furthermore, in Scala Strings are collections. Internally they are just plain old Java Strings for which there exists some implicit conversions to give them the full power of the Scala collection library. But for users they can be seen as collections.

In your example `foreach` iterates over each element of the string and executes a closure on them (which is the body of the for-comprehension or the argument in the `foreach` call).

Even more information about for-comprehensions can be found in section 7 of the [StackOverflow Scala Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info).