# How to express [42 | x == y] with for comprehensions?

Tags: scala, list-comprehension, for-comprehension

I have some pieces of code where I generate multiple lists (via for comprehensions) and then concatenate them. There are some one-element lists where this doesn't work though. In Haskell I would do something like

```
[42 | i == j]
```

which equivalently is

```
(do guard (i == j)
    return 42) :: [Int]
```

or

```
(guard (i == j) >>= \_ -> return 1) :: [Int]
```

In Scala I tried

```
for (if i == j) yield 42
```

but it says "illegal start of simple pattern".

[In an answer to what Scala's yield is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/60982) the author says 'Scala's "for comprehensions" are equivalent to Haskell's "do" notation'.

Also, on the [Scala website](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111) it says "Comprehensions have the form *for (enums) yield e*, where enums refers to a semicolon-separated list of enumerators. An enumerator is either a generator which introduces new variables, or it is a filter". But clearly, this is not the case, as filters seem to be only allowed *after* generators.

At the moment I use

```
if (i == j) List(42) else Nil
```

I probably wouldn't prefer the for comprehension syntax anyway for this special case, and just use if-then-else instead. In Haskell, it looks quite nice though due to the similarity to the mathematical set-builder notation.

My question is not about style, but more about technical details: Why is there a difference in this specific case between Haskell and Scala? Why isn't `for (if i == j) yield 42` working?

Comment: I'm quite surprised that the list comprehension in Haskell actually works. I would have expected to require at least one generator in a comprehension as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A closest equvalent of `[42 | i == j]` would probably be `for (x <- List(42) if i == j) yield x`.

`for (if i == j) yield 42` is illegal because a filter (`if` part) must follow some generator (`x <- List(42)` in my example).

[Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) states (*6.19 For Comprehensions and For Loops*):

Syntax:

```
Expr1       ::= ‘for’ (‘(’ Enumerators ‘)’ | ‘{’ Enumerators ‘}’)
                  {nl} [‘yield’] Expr
Enumerators ::= Generator {semi Enumerator}
Enumerator  ::= Generator
                | Guard
                | ‘val’ Pattern1 ‘=’ Expr
Generator   ::= Pattern1 ‘<-’ Expr [Guard]
Guard       ::= ‘if’ PostfixExpr
```

As you can see, there's at least one generator required in `Enumerators`.

**EDIT**:

By the way, I think `if (i == j) List(42) else Nil` is the right thing to do since it is not Haskell. It is clean and most likely faster because it constructs a list just once and doesn't call any additional methods.

My example is translated by compiler into `List(42) withFilter (x => i == j) map (x => x)` (it actually may be optimized, I'm not sure) and can be abbreviated to `List(42) filter (x => i == j)`. You can see, it constructs the initial list, than calls a method which creates a new list, and this method takes anonymous function, which in Scala is also an object (but probably it is also optimized). I think it is inefficient way to do such a simple job.

Comment: I accepted this answer for the moment, but I'm still interested in why exactly there is a difference, or: what is `(guard (i == j) >>= \_ -> return 1) :: [Int]` in Scala? I updated the question with that Haskell snippet. I think som-snytt's answer has some hints on that.