# How to use applicative functors to combine Scalaz validations

Tags: validation, scala, scalaz, scalaz7

Cannot figure out if it is possible to write something like this using Scalaz 7. I have tried to express myself with the comments inside the code block.

```
def validate1(p: String) = ValidationNel[String, Value] = ...
def validate2(p: String) = ValidationNel[String, Value] = ...

validateCombination(p1: String, p2: String) = {
  // I would like to write something like
  (validate1(p1) |@| validate2(p2)) { (v1, v1) =>
    // And validate the combinations here and return successNel of failNel
  }
}

def validate(p1: String, p2: String, p3: String) = {
  (validateCombination(p1, p2) |@| validate1(p3)) { (v1, v2, v3) =>
    // Notice the three parameters I want to have here
  }
}
```

I just end up with different types of confusing compilation errors in validateCombinations or just 2 parameters for the applicative functor I get inside validate function, one of them being of type ValidationNel[...].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `.flatMap(identity)` in method `validateCombination` to produce `ValidationNel[String, (Value, Value)]` and `pattern matching` in method `validate` like this:

```
def validateCombination(p1: String, p2: String): ValidationNel[String, (Value, Value)] = {
  // I would like to write something like
  (validate1(p1) |@| validate2(p2)) { (v1, v1) =>
    (v1, v2).successNel[String]
  }.flatMap(identity)
}

def validate(p1: String, p2: String, p3: String) = {
  (validateCombination(p1, p2) |@| validate1(p3)) { case ((v1, v2), v3) =>
    // Notice the three parameters I want to have here
  }
}
```

**flatMap(identity)**

Normally you would use method `flatten` on nested containers to get `M[T]` from `M[M[T]]`. It works on `Future`, `Option`, `Try`, collections and so on.

In this case `type M[T] = ValidationNel[String, T]`.

I don't know why there is no method `flatten` in `Validation`, but you could always use `flatMap(identity)` instead of `flatten`.

**match**

As [Ben James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189179/ben-james) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919016/how-to-use-applicative-functors-to-combine-scalaz-validations/16919236?noredirect=1#comment24423242_16919236), `flatMap` on `Validation` is dubious. You could always use `match` instead of it:

```
(validate1(p1) |@| validate2(p2)) { (v1, v1) =>
  (v1, v2).successNel[String]
} match {
  case Success(s) => s
  case Failure(f) => Failure(f)
}
```

**pattern matching**

Pattern matching is the common way to deal with tuples. For instance it's vary useful with `foldLeft` method, like `foldLeft(1 -> 2){ case ((a, b), c) => ??? }`.

If you find yourself using getters `_N` on `Tuple` you are probably should use pattern matching.

**for comprehension**

As [Daniel C. Sobral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel-c-sobral) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919016/how-to-use-applicative-functors-to-combine-scalaz-validations/16919236?noredirect=1#comment24422659_16919236) for comprehension could be easier to understand.

You could use it in your `validate` method like this:

```
def validate(p1: String, p2: String, p3: String) = {
  for{
    (v1, v2) <- validateCombination(p1, p2) // pattern matching
    v3 <- validate1(p3)
  } yield ??? // Your code here
}
```

It involves pattern matching without `case` keyword.

Note that for comprehension calls `flatMap` on `validateCombination(p1, p2)`, so you'll lost error messages from `validate1(p3)` in case `validateCombination(p1, p2)` is `Failure`. On the contrary, `|@|` collects all error messages from both sides.

Comment: Though I'd use the for comprehension -- it is easier to understand, imho.

Comment: `Validation` doesn't have flatten because it isn't intended to have a monad. In fact, the `flatMap` method is dubious. But there are methods for running operations over the `\/` equivalent of the validation and converting back again, e.g. `v.disjunctioned(_.flatten)`

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: do you mean "for comprehension instead of `|@|`"? I thought the point is to keep `|@|` untouched. Thank you for suggestion. Do you mind I'll add it to my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I actually first tried this using for comprehensions but I run into problems like "could not find implicit value for parameter M: scalaz.Monoid[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String]]" when writing code like for (v1 <- validate1(p1); v2 <- validate(p2); if (isValidCombination(v1, v2))

Comment: @Lauri: there is no method `withFilter` in [`Validation`](http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.0-1-6.0/doc.sxr/scalaz/Validation.scala.html), so you can't use `if` statement in for comprehension. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/406435).

Comment: I meant for comprehension instead of `flatMap`.