# Slick where/filter/withFilter

Tags: scala, slick

In slick (1.0), what is the difference between doing `.where()`, `.filter()` and `.withFilter()` on a Table?

In the [API](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/api/#scala.slick.lifted.Query) they have similar signature but it's not clear how they differ:

```
def filter[T]            (f: (E) ⇒ T)(implicit wt:   CanBeQueryCondition[T]): Query[E, U]
def where[T <: Column[_]](f: (E) ⇒ T)(implicit arg0: CanBeQueryCondition[T]): Query[E, U]
def withFilter[T]        (f: (E) ⇒ T)(implicit arg0: CanBeQueryCondition[T]): Query[E, U]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/lifted/Query.scala#L39) all this methods are the same:

```
def withFilter[T : CanBeQueryCondition](f: E => T) = filter(f)
def where[T <: Column[_] : CanBeQueryCondition](f: E => T) = filter(f)
```

**filter** is the common method to filter collections in scala. There is `filter` method in collections, `Option`, `Future`, `Try` and so on.

**withFilter** is there for [`for comprehensions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/406435). `if` statement in for comprehensions is translated into call of `withFilter`.

I guess **where** is added by analogy with `SQL` `where` statement.