# How do I filter a list with functional programming in scala?

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

I have two lists:

```
val list1 = List("asdf", "fdas", "afswd", "dsf", "twea", "rewgds", "werwe", "dsadfs");
val list2 = List();
```

I want to filter all items from list1 and setup list2 so that it only contains items that don't contain the letter 'a'.  I know how to do this with imperative programming, but how would I do this with functional programing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost literal representation of your requirement definition:

```
val list2 = list1.filterNot(item => item.contains('a'))
// List[String] = List(dsf, rewgds, werwe)
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I really need though is to figure out something that doesn't have a default implementation already by Scala. Let's say I have an object and I want to call getId() on each object and then return only the items whose ID contains an 'a' character?

Comment: I deleted my post that illustrated this but iterating through would work for any object.

Comment: @TritonMan it will be quite the same: `xs.filter(obj => obj.getId.contains('a'))` (note, filterNot versus filter). One might write the former code as `list1.filter(item => !item.contains('a'))`, but I prefer this filter/filterNot way.

Answer (score 3):

In response to your comment on @om-nom-nom's answer:

```
val list2 = for(item <- list1 if !item.contains("a")) yield item
```

Comment: Just as a side note, both @cmbaxter and mine solutions [will be desugared to a nearly the same code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/298389).

Comment: yeah I think I get that.  Also, it looks like maybe I can use _.contains() instead of the "item => item.contains()".  Is that the same thing?

Comment: @TritonMan yep, it is shorthand syntax