# Is there a Scala equivalent to Python's list comprehension?

Tags: python, scala, list, list-comprehension

I'm translating some of my Python code to Scala, and I was wondering if there's an equivalent to Python's list-comprehension:

```
[x for x in list if x!=somevalue]
```

Essentially I'm trying to remove certain elements from the list if it matches.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The closest analogue to a Python list comprehension would be

```
for (x <- list if x != somevalue) yield x
```

But since you're what you're doing is filtering, you might as well just use the `filter` method

```
list.filter(_ != somevalue)
```

or

```
list.filterNot(_ == somevalue)
```

Comment: @Shelby.S by the way, former two [will be desugared to the identical code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/298389)