# scala for each loop got error when convert java to scala

Tags: java, scala, foreach, scala-java-interop

i am working with scala in few days. and i am really confused with this problem .

i really tried to solve the peoblem but i can't..

My java code

```
@Override
    public void saveOrUpdateAll(Collection<T> entities) {
        Session session = getSession();
        for (T entity : entities) {
            session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        }
    }
```

Scala Code

```
@Override
    def  saveOrUpdateAll( entities:Collection[T]){
        var session:Session = getSession()
        var entity:T=null
        for (entity :entities) {
            session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        }
    }
```

search for scala for each. and am really confused about that .. if you know how to solve this problem please share your answer here.. and Thanx..

with regards Milano..  :)

Comment: You want `<-` instead of `:` in the `for` in Scala, and you don't need the `var entity` line at all.

Comment: @RexKerr u r r8.. pls answer it and i will mark as correct answer and this is really help full ans thankx...

Comment: senia's got the more complete correct answer.

Comment: @RexKerr mm.. okay.. your r r8.. and really thanks for your comments.. it's really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```scala
override def saveOrUpdateAll(entities: Collection[T]){
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  val session: Session = getSession()

  for (entity <- entities.asScala) {
      session.saveOrUpdate(entity)
  }
}
```

There is no for each loop in scala. You should wrap your collection using `JavaConverters` and use [for-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/406435) here.

`JavaConverters` wraps `Collection` using [`Wrappers.JCollectionWrapper`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$) [without](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/convert/Wrappers.scala#L57) memory overhead.

Comment: @milano: if you want to override a method of parent class you should use [override modifier](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/composition-and-inheritance.html#10.8).