# Understanding how for statements are represented by map, flatMap and Filter

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the below code:

```
val e1 = 10 :: 15 :: 20 :: 25 :: Nil
val e2 = 10 :: 15 :: 20 :: 25 :: Nil

val y = for {
    e <- e1 if(e%2==0)
} yield e

val y1 = e1.withFilter(x => (x%2 == 0)).map(Int=>Int)

val e31 = for{
    i <- e1
    j <- e2 if (isPrime(i+j))
} yield(i,j)
```

Now as you can see `y` and `y1` both are giving me exact same value, which proves that I am successfully represented `for` statement having (single generater + filter) with withFilter and map.

But when I am having a `for` statement with multiple generator and filter (example: val `e31`), I am not able to find out how can I represent that with map, filterMap and withFilter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> val e31 = for{
     |     i <- e1
     |     j <- e2
     |     if ((i+j) % 2 == 0)
     |     } yield(i,j)
res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((10,10), (10,20), (15,15), (15,25), (20,10), (20,20), (25,15), (25,25))


scala> e1.flatMap(i => e2.withFilter(j => ((i+j)%2 == 0)).map(j => (i,j)))
res2: List[(Int, Int)] = List((10,10), (10,20), (15,15), (15,25), (20,10), (20,20), (25,15), (25,25))
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/what-is-scalas-yield) question for a more detailed answer on how each for-construct is translated.

Comment: Thanks Marth. It really helps me to understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a way to force the Scala compiler to show us how it desugars `for` comprehensions.

For example, when compiling this code:

```
object dummy {    
  val e31 = for{
  i <- e1
  j <- e2
  if (isPrime(i+j))
  } yield(i,j)
}
```

with `scalac -Xprint:parser dummy.scala`, you'll get:

```
[[syntax trees at end of                    parser]] // dummy.scala
package <empty> {
  object dummy extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    val e31 = e1.flatMap(((i) => e2.withFilter(((j) => isPrime(i.$plus(j)))).map(((j) => scala.Tuple2(i, j)))))
  }
}
```

The code has errors (various identifiers are undefined) but it doesn't matter here, since `parser` doesn't see these errors yet.