# What is the Swift equivalent of -[NSObject description]?

Tags: swift

In Objective-C, one can add a `description` method to their class to aid in debugging:

```
@implementation MyClass
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@: %p, foo = %@>", [self class], foo _foo];
}
@end
```

Then in the debugger, you can do:

```
po fooClass
<MyClass: 0x12938004, foo = "bar">
```

What is the equivalent in Swift? Swift's REPL output can be helpful:

```
  1> class MyClass { let foo = 42 }
  2> 
  3> let x = MyClass()
x: MyClass = {
  foo = 42
}
```

But I'd like to override this behavior for printing to the console:

```
  4> println("x = \(x)")
x = C11lldb_expr_07MyClass (has 1 child)
```

Is there a way to clean up this `println` output? I've seen the `Printable` protocol:

```
/// This protocol should be adopted by types that wish to customize their
/// textual representation.  This textual representation is used when objects
/// are written to an `OutputStream`.
protocol Printable {
    var description: String { get }
}
```

I figured this would automatically be "seen" by `println` but it does not appear to be the case:

```
  1> class MyClass: Printable {
  2.     let foo = 42
  3.     var description: String { get { return "MyClass, foo = \(foo)" } }
  4. }   
  5> 
  6> let x = MyClass()
x: MyClass = {
  foo = 42
}
  7> println("x = \(x)")
x = C11lldb_expr_07MyClass (has 1 child)
```

And instead I have to explicitly call description:

```
 8> println("x = \(x.description)")
x = MyClass, foo = 42
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

To implement this on a Swift type you must implement the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol and then also implement a string property called `description`.

For example:

```
class MyClass: CustomStringConvertible {
    let foo = 42

    var description: String {
        return "<\(type(of: self)): foo = \(foo)>"
    }
}

print(MyClass()) // prints: <MyClass: foo = 42>
```

Note: `type(of: self)` gets the type of the current instances instead of explicitly writing ‘MyClass’.

Comment: Great find! I'm going to file a radar -- println output of "swift -i sample.swift" and "swift sample.swift && sample" differ.

Comment: Thanks for the info on that.  I was trying out Printable in a playground and indeed it doesn't work right now.  Good it hear it works in a app.

Comment: Printable does work in the playground, but iff the class descends from NSObject

Comment: In Swift 2.0 it has changed to CustomStringConvertible and CustomDebugStringConvertible

Comment: Also, there is no issue using CustomStringConvertible and CustomDebugStringConvertible in Playground with Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 55):

**Example of using `CustomStringConvertible` and `CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocols in Swift:**

**PageContentViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class PageContentViewController: UIViewController {

    var pageIndex : Int = 0

    override var description : String { 
        return "**** PageContentViewController\npageIndex equals \(pageIndex) ****\n" 
    }

    override var debugDescription : String { 
        return "---- PageContentViewController\npageIndex equals \(pageIndex) ----\n" 
    }

            ...
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    /*
        Called after the controller's view is loaded into memory.
    */
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myPageContentViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("A") as! PageContentViewController
        print(myPageContentViewController)       
        print(myPageContentViewController.description)
        print(myPageContentViewController.debugDescription)
    }

          ...
}
```

**Which print out:**

```
**** PageContentViewController
pageIndex equals 0 ****

**** PageContentViewController
pageIndex equals 0 ****

---- PageContentViewController
pageIndex equals 0 ----
```

**Note:** if you have a custom class which does not inherit from any class included in **UIKit** or **Foundation** libraries, then make it inherit of `NSObject` class or make it conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and `CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocols.

Comment: the function must declared as public

Answer (score 37):

Just use `CustomStringConvertible` and `var description: String { return "Some string" }`

works in Xcode 7.0 beta

```
class MyClass: CustomStringConvertible {
  var string: String?


  var description: String {
     //return "MyClass \(string)"
     return "\(self.dynamicType)"
  }
}

var myClass = MyClass()  // this line outputs MyClass nil

// and of course 
print("\(myClass)")

// Use this newer versions of Xcode
var description: String {
    //return "MyClass \(string)"
    return "\(type(of: self))"
}
```

Answer (score 22):

The answers relating to `CustomStringConvertible` are the way to go.  Personally, to keep the class (or struct) definition as clean as possible, I would also separate out the description code into a separate extension:

```
class foo {
    // Just the basic foo class stuff.
    var bar = "Humbug!"
}

extension foo: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return bar
    }
}

let xmas = foo()
print(xmas)  // Prints "Humbug!"
```

Answer (score 10):

As described [here](https://medium.com/@YogevSitton/use-auto-describing-objects-with-customstringconvertible-49528b55f446), you can also use Swift's reflection capabilities to make your classes generate their own description by using this extension:

```
extension CustomStringConvertible {
    var description : String {
        var description: String = "\(type(of: self)){ "
        let selfMirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in selfMirror.children {
            if let propertyName = child.label {
                description += "\(propertyName): \(child.value), "
            }
        }
        description = String(description.dropLast(2))
        description += " }"
        return description
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
class SomeBaseClass: CustomStringConvertible {

    //private var string: String = "SomeBaseClass"

    var description: String {
        return "\(self.dynamicType)"
    }

    // Use this in newer versions of Xcode
    var description: String {
        return "\(type(of: self))"
    }

}

class SomeSubClass: SomeBaseClass {
    // If needed one can override description here

}


var mySomeBaseClass = SomeBaseClass()
// Outputs SomeBaseClass
var mySomeSubClass = SomeSubClass()
// Outputs SomeSubClass
var myOtherBaseClass = SomeSubClass()
// Outputs SomeSubClass
```

Answer (score 5):

```
struct WorldPeace: CustomStringConvertible {
    let yearStart: Int
    let yearStop: Int

    var description: String {
        return "\(yearStart)-\(yearStop)"
    }
}

let wp = WorldPeace(yearStart: 2020, yearStop: 2040)
print("world peace: \(wp)")

// outputs:
// world peace: 2020-2040
```