# Card simpleDescription() doesn't work in Apple's swift example

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

I'm implementing Apple's example of using enums to create a Card `struct`, but the `simpleDescription()` method doesn't work. Apple suggests:

```
struct Card {
   var rank: Rank
   var suit: Suit
   func simpleDescription() -> String {
      return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
   }
}
```

but when I call

```
let card = Card(rank: .queen, suit: .hearts)
print("card = \(Card(rank: .queen, suit: .hearts))")
```

the console prints out

```
card = Card(rank: twoMatch.Rank.queen, suit: twoMatch.Suit.hearts)
```

where "twoMatch" is the name of my app, and ignores the string I've constructed in `simpleDescription()`. I've checked the method signature several times and have even copied it over from the examples in `Rank` and `Suit`, which work just fine.

Comment: You're defining the wrong method. That's just some arbitrary name in one of Apple's samples. Check this out instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108634/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-nsobject-description

Comment: Can you send your full code, with Rank and Suit définitions.

Comment: @FernandoMazzon I'm laughing at myself. That's it. How do I acknowledge you formally in a comment??

Comment: @hkatz i'll move it to an answer if you want to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the wrong method. That's just some arbitrary name in one of Apple's samples. Check this out instead:

[What is the Swift equivalent of -[NSObject description]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108634/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-nsobject-description)