# calling method from struct in swift

Tags: methods, struct, enums, swift

I found what looks like an elegant solution to iterating over enums here: [How to enumerate an enum with String type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007461/how-to-enumerate-an-enum-with-string-type/24222118#24222118)

Next, I'm having trouble figuring out how to call this method.  At face value, it doesn't look like it takes an argument, but when I try to call Card.createDeck() I get a compiler error telling me "error: missing argument for parameter #1 in call".

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here?  What am I supposed to pass to this method?

```
struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
    }

    func createDeck() -> [Card] {

        var deck = [Card]()

        var n = 1
        while let rank = Rank.fromRaw(n) {

            var m = 1
            while let suit = Suit.fromRaw(m) {
                deck += Card(rank: rank, suit: suit)
                m++
            }
            n++
        }

        return deck
    }

}
```

Comment: As said below, I figured out that because this is not an instance method, I need to use `static func`.  However, when I call this now via `Card.createDeck()` I just see all the enums.  How do I unwrap those?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`createDeck()` is a instance method. Doing `Card.createDeck()` is a call to a class method that doesn't exist.

`class func` - for class methods

Edit:

I misread that it was a struct, but the same logic applies.

`static func` - for static methods

Comment: I just figured out from some other sleuthing that I need to use `static` before my `func`.  This seems to be in line with your nudge, @literphor :-)

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't see it was a struct, otherwise you would use static.

Comment: Thanks @literphor; next up, how to unwrap these enums that are flying at me? :-)

Comment: @davidjpeacock Either optional chaining `if let myEnum = myRank? { } else { } ` or unsafely force the unwrapping `let myEnum = myRank!`

Answer (score 3):

You can not able to call it directly as you need instace of `struct` as it is not class function.So use

```
Card(rank:Rank.yourRank,suit:Suit.yourSuit).createDeck()
```

Actually to make `struct` you need `rank` and `suit` instance so first make them and than pass to `Card` constructor.By default `struct` have arguments as their properties.