# Calling a method from a struct within the same class

Tags: swift, class, struct

I'd like to logically organize class properties to signify that they are one logical unit and to distinguish them from other class properties that are less tightly related.

I thought of doing this using a struct within my class. However, it seems that I can't call class methods from the struct property setters. I get what seems to be an inappropriate compile error: "missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

This seems to be different from [calling method from struct in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046226/calling-method-from-struct-in-swift)
where the function is within the struct. In my case, the methods are generic and don't just apply to my struct but to all class properties. Therefore, I don't want to move them within the struct.

Do you have ideas on how to organize properties into tight(er) logical units within classes?

```
class MyClass {
    struct MyStruct {
        static var aVarInMyStruct: String? {
            didSet {
                anotherVarInMyStruct = foo()        // This gives compile error "missing argument for parameter #1 in call"
            }
        }
        static var anotherVarInMyStruct: String?
    }

    func foo() {
        println("I am foo()")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The inner type `MyStruct` knows nothing about its outer type `MyClass`. So there is no `foo` function to call from `MyStruct`. To better organize your code I suggest you to use `// MARK: - whatever this section is` comments. Types are not here to organize codes. Types are here to create right abstractions for the program.

Answer (score 1):

I fix your bug:

```
     class MyClass {
    struct MyStruct {
        static var aVarInMyStruct: String? {
            didSet {
                anotherVarInMyStruct = MyClass.foo()        // This gives compile error "missing argument for parameter #1 in call"
            }
        }
        static var anotherVarInMyStruct: String?
    }

    static  func foo()->String {
        println("I am foo()")
        return "it is ok"
    }
}
```

Comment: This even does not compile

Comment: sorry  I forget adding a return value ,it's work now

Comment: the static key words also replace with class