# Introspection and iteration on an Enum

Tags: swift, enums, swift2, introspection

Is it possible to programatically find out how many "cases" an Enum has in Swift 2 and iterate over them?

This code doesn't compile, but it gives yo an idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
enum HeaderStyles{

    case h1
    case h2
    case h3
}

for item in HeaderStyles{
    print(item)
}
```

Comment: Enums have to be declared at compile time, therefore you - the developer - know exactly how many cases an enum has. ;-)

Comment: I have an answer you can refer to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48960126/5372480

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a generic struct that provide that iteration ability. In example below the enum raw values must start with 0 (it does it by default) and have no gaps between raw values (can't have raw values such as 0,1,2,3,5 -- 4 is missing)

```
public struct EnumGenerator<T> : GeneratorType, SequenceType {
    private let enumInit: Int -> T?
    private var i: Int = 0
    public mutating func next() -> T? { return enumInit(i++) }
    public init(_ initFunc: Int -> T?){ self.enumInit = initFunc}
}

enum HeaderStyles:Int{
    case h1
    case h2
    case h3
}

for item in EnumGenerator(HeaderStyles.init){
    print(item)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to iterate over all cases is to make a computed property which returns an `Array` of them:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case Zero, One, Two

    static var allCases: [SomeEnum] {
        return [.Zero, .One, .Two]
    }
}
```

If you want an automatic array you could use `Int` as rawValue so you don't have to change any code if you add an additional `case`:

**Swift 3/4:** `++` and `--` were removed and `anyGenerator` was renamed to `AnyIterator`

```
enum SomeEnum: Int {
    case Zero, One, Two

    static var allCases: [SomeEnum] {
        var i = 0
        return Array(AnyIterator{
            let newEnum = SomeEnum(rawValue: i)
            i += 1
            return newEnum
        })
    }
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
enum SomeEnum: Int {
    case Zero, One, Two

    static var allCases: [SomeEnum] {
        var i = 0
        return Array(anyGenerator{ SomeEnum(rawValue: i++) })
    }
}
```

In both cases you would use it like this:

```
for num in SomeEnum.allCases {
    // ...
}
```