# Make a type itself -- not its instances -- conform to a protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I was wondering if it is possible in Swift to make a type conform to a protocol, so that I can treat the type itself as conforming to a protocol the way one normally treats instances as conforming to a protocol. Example code:

```
protocol P {
    func f()
}

class C where C.self: P { // Not actual code
    static func f() {
        print("Because C.f: ()->() exists, C.self should satisfy the protocol.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [Iterating through an Enum in Swift 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41352594/2976878). I believe the short answer is no – metatype types cannot conform to protocols.

Comment: @Hamish Man, I wish. It'd be nice to be able to use classes with class methods (note: `class`, not `static`) to conform to interfaces, rather than using the singleton pattern. At least Swift has 2 liner singletons which are lazy and thread safe :D

Comment: @Alexander Yeah :/ Put it on the seemingly infinite wish-list of features that would be really awesome for Swift to have, but doesn't (yet). Might be worth filing an improvement request or bringing it up on the evolution mailing list though – at least now that we're entering the phase of less source-breaking but more additive changes to the language.