# Swiftier Swift for 'add to array, or create if not there...'

Tags: swift

I've noticed a common pattern in Swift is

```
var x:[String:[Thing]] = [:]
```

so, when you want to "add an item to one of the arrays", you can not just

```
x[which].append(t)
```

you have to

```
if x.index(forKey: which) == nil {
    x[which] = []
    }
x[which]!.append(s!)
```

Really, is there a swiftier way to say something like

```
  x[index?!?!].append??(s?!)
```

- While this is a question about style, **performance seems to be a critical issue when touching arrays in Swift**, due to the copy-wise nature of Swift.

(Please note, obviously you can use an extension for this; it's a question about Swiftiness.)

Comment: By the way, here is a spectacular fragment for correctly putting classes in a dictionary in Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42459639/294884

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that with a single subscript+append call (without custom extension). – Possible approaches, apart from what you said: `x[which] = (x[which] ?? []) + [s]` or `if x[which]?.append(s) == nil { x[which] = [s] }`. I *assume* that this has been asked before, but cannot find it currently.

Comment: both of those are brilliant man

Comment: Both will make a copy of the array – see http://stackoverflow.com/q/41079687/2976878 for a way to avoid this. [SE-0154](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0154-dictionary-key-and-value-collections.md) will improve the situation, but AFAIK still won't allow you to use any particulary slick syntax in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: wait @hamish - purely in terms of performance (no style consideration)  ... the original code in my question (4 lines of code) - surely that sucker is not making a copy anywhere, right?  cheers

Comment: @JoeBlow `x[which]!.append(s!)` will indeed make a copy of the array. The problem is that a temporary variable needs to be used in order to hold the *unwrapped* value for a given key (regardless of whether you force unwrap or optional chain). It's that temporary array which is appended to, and then re-inserted back into the dictionary. Because both the dictionary and temporary array have a view onto the underlying array buffer, a copy will be triggered upon appending.

Comment: @JoeBlow You can easily test this behaviour btw with [this test setup](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/9723fa958b0a9d64bb8627e00c0c04a5), although note that for non-optional subscript returns in the stdlib, it's possible for a pointer to the underlying value to be passed back to the caller (through a `mutableAddressWithNativeOwner` subscript accessor), allowing for a direct mutation. That's what will allow the proposal SE-0154 to efficiently perform direct mutations of a dictionary's values :)

Comment: *"x[which]!.append(s!) will indeed make a copy of the array."*  holy God!    thanks as always for that info man.

Comment: @Fattie: Things became simpler in Swift 4, see update below.

Comment: magnificent @MartinR, thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Swift 4 update:**

As of Swift 4, dictionaries have a [`subscript(_:default:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript) method, so that

```
dict[key, default: []].append(newElement)
```

appends to the already present array, or to an empty array. Example:

```
var dict: [String: [Int]] = [:]
print(dict["foo"]) // nil

dict["foo", default: []].append(1)
print(dict["foo"]) // Optional([1])

dict["foo", default: []].append(2)
print(dict["foo"]) // Optional([1, 2])
```

As of **Swift 4.1** (currently in beta) this is also *fast,*
compare Hamish's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079687/dictionary-in-swift-with-mutable-array-as-value-is-performing-very-slow-how-to/41154903#comment83886568_41154903).

---

*Previous answer for Swift <= 3:* There is – as far as I know – no way to "create or update" a dictionary
value with a single subscript call.

In addition to what you wrote, you can use the nil-coalescing operator

```
dict[key] = (dict[key] ?? []) + [elem]
```

or optional chaining (which returns `nil` if the append operation
could *not* be performed):

```
if dict[key]?.append(elem) == nil {
     dict[key] = [elem]
}
```

As mentioned in [SE-0154 Provide Custom Collections for Dictionary Keys and Values](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0154-dictionary-key-and-value-collections.md) and also by @Hamish in the comments, both methods
make a copy of the array.

With the implementation of SE-0154 you will be able to mutate
a dictionary value without making a copy:

```
if let i = dict.index(forKey: key) {
    dict.values[i].append(elem)
} else {
    dict[key] = [key]
}
```

At present, the most efficient solution is given by Rob Napier
in [Dictionary in Swift with Mutable Array as value is performing very slow? How to optimize or construct properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079687/dictionary-in-swift-with-mutable-array-as-value-is-performing-very-slow-how-to/41154903#41154903):

```
var array = dict.removeValue(forKey: key) ?? []
array.append(elem)
dict[key] = array
```

---

A simple benchmark confirms that "Rob's method" is the fastest:

```
let numKeys = 1000
let numElements = 1000

do {
    var dict: [Int: [Int]] = [:]

    let start = Date()
    for key in 1...numKeys {
        for elem in 1...numElements {
            if dict.index(forKey: key) == nil {
                dict[key] = []
            }
            dict[key]!.append(elem)

        }
    }
    let end = Date()
    print("Your method:", end.timeIntervalSince(start))
}

do {
    var dict: [Int: [Int]] = [:]

    let start = Date()
    for key in 1...numKeys {
        for elem in 1...numElements {
            dict[key] = (dict[key] ?? []) + [elem]
        }
    }
    let end = Date()
    print("Nil coalescing:", end.timeIntervalSince(start))
}


do {
    var dict: [Int: [Int]] = [:]

    let start = Date()
    for key in 1...numKeys {
        for elem in 1...numElements {
            if dict[key]?.append(elem) == nil {
                dict[key] = [elem]
            }
        }
    }
    let end = Date()
    print("Optional chaining", end.timeIntervalSince(start))
}

do {
    var dict: [Int: [Int]] = [:]

    let start = Date()
    for key in 1...numKeys {
        for elem in 1...numElements {
            var array = dict.removeValue(forKey: key) ?? []
            array.append(elem)
            dict[key] = array
        }
    }
    let end = Date()
    print("Remove and add:", end.timeIntervalSince(start))
}
```

Results (on a 1.2 GHz Intel Core m5 MacBook) for 1000 keys/1000 elements:

```
Your method:      0.470084965229034
Nil coalescing:   0.460215032100677
Optional chaining 0.397282958030701
Remove and add:   0.160293996334076
```

And for 1000 keys/10,000 elements:

```
Your method:      14.6810429692268
Nil coalescing:   15.1537700295448
Optional chaining 14.4717089533806
Remove and add:   1.54668599367142
```

Comment: the most dramatic results are if you go 10/100,000 ... Your method: 28
Nil coalescing: 32
Optional chaining 28
Remove and add: 0.76 !