# Swift - Adding value to an array inside a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of objects which I want to store it in dictionary based on student id. In my dictionary my key is of type String and value is an array of string. How do I append the values in the array?

My student array:

```
var studentArray = [Student(id: '1', subject: 'History'), Student(id: '2', subject: 'History'), Student(id:'1', subject: 'Maths')]
```

My final dictionary should be like:

```
{'1': ['History', 'Maths'], '2': ['History']}
```

My code:

```
var dictionary = [String, [String]]()
for student in studentArray {
   dictionary.updateValue(student.subject, forKey: student.id)
}
```

This gives me output as:

```
{'1': ['Maths'], '2': ['History']}
```

I tried: `dictionary[student.id].append([student.subject])` but this gives me nil output.

How do I append the value to an array inside the dictionary?

Comment: Reduce into would be good also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2924692-reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Thanks to Martin's comment. The snippet below is the the most succinct answer I can think of. I was *initially* coming at it from a wrong direction. and I was getting an error. See comments

```
struct Student { 
    let id: Int
    let subject : String
}

var studentArray = [Student(id: 1, subject: "History"), Student(id: 2, subject: "History"), Student(id:1, subject: "Maths")]

typealias Subject = String
var dict : [Int: [Subject]] = [:]

for student in studentArray {

    (dict[student.id, default: []]).append(student.subject)
}

print(dict)
```

---

**Previous answers:**

```
struct Student { 
    let id: Int
    let subject : String
}

var studentArray = [Student(id: 1, subject: "History"), Student(id: 2, subject: "History"), Student(id:1, subject: "Maths")]

typealias Subject = String
var dict : [Int: [Subject]] = [:]

for student in studentArray {
    var subjects = dict[student.id] ?? [String]()
    subjects.append(student.subject)
    dict[student.id] = subjects
}

print(dict)
```

Or you can do it this way:

```
struct Student { 
    let id: Int
    let subject : String
}

var studentArray = [Student(id: 1, subject: "History"), Student(id: 2, subject: "History"), Student(id:1, subject: "Maths")]

typealias Subject = String
var dict : [Int: [Subject]] = [:]

for student in studentArray {
    if let _ = dict[student.id]{
        dict[student.id]!.append(student.subject)
    }else{
        dict[student.id] = [student.subject]
    }
}

print(dict)
```

whichever you like

Comment: his code doesn't compile. he's using `'`. And it's an integer. I just assumed myself. typealias is just for improved readability...

Comment: Simpler: `dict[student.id, default: []].append(student.subject)` – compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42486686/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Aha. That's what I was trying to do. I was doing `(dict[student.id] ?? [String]()).append(student.subject)` which didn't work. I was getting the following error: **cannot use mutating member on immutable value: `'??'` returns immutable value**. I had to change my approach

Comment: `let dict = students.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.id, default: []].append($1.subject) }`

Answer (score 4):

Everyone here is overcomplicating this. There's a dedicated API for this task lol

```
struct Student {
    let id: Int
    let subject: String
}

let students = [
    Student(id: 1, subject: "History"),
    Student(id: 2, subject: "History"),
    Student(id: 1, subject: "Maths")
]

let subjectsByStudentID = Dictionary
    .init(grouping: students, by: { $0.id })
    .mapValues { students in students.map { $0.subject } }

print(subjectsByStudentID) // => [2: ["History"], 1: ["History", "Maths"]]
```

Comment: Great, I didn't knew that API.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this should works:

```swift
var dictionary = [String: [String]]()

for student in studentArray {
    if dictionary[student.id] == nil {
        dictionary[student.id] = [String]()
    }
    dictionary[student.id]?.append(student.subject)
}
```

Comment: `dictionary[student.id]?` is `nil`