# Swift work around to make `AnyObject.Type` conform to `Equatable`?

Tags: swift, comparable, equatable

I would like to make `AnyClass` (AKA `AnyObject.Type`) conform to `Equatable` so that when I have an array with `AnyClass` elements (`Array<AnyClass>`), I can call `remove(Element:)`, but this requires `Element` to conform to `Equatable`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value (it may actually be a duplicate).

Comment: @rmaddy No, this is a question specific to the fact that extensions to `AnyClass` are not allowed by the compiler, thus, making it not possible for `AnyClass` to conform to `Equatable` as used in the thread you provided

Comment: Before you are going to spend more effort to accomplish that consider whether you can find a common denominator of the affected classes for example a protocol. This kind of *AnyClass / AnyObject fake generics* is worse than finding a common ground.

Comment: Compare [Make a Swift dictionary where the key is “Type”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42459484/2976878) – you *could* build a wrapper type for this (or else just use `.filter {$0 != someMetatype}`). Although that being said, I am wondering on the use of an `[AnyClass]` – what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Hamish I am mapping set of unique keys to a set of classes related to those keys. For example: `["public.php" : [CodeEditor.self, TextEditor.self, WebViewer.self]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Since Swift 3 you could use `AnyHashable` as a replacement for `AnyObject`. It represents any value which conforms to the `Equatable` protocol.

Instead of

```
var array:[AnyObject] = []
```

just write

```
var array:[AnyHashable] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually think what your trying to acheive is possible, or whether you should even try to do it in this way.

Classes are generally represent real world objects, whether this is a car, a view or soemthing completely different. So it's very difficult to say is ANY custom I class I create the same as this other custom class I created.

Swift just doesn't know how to compare them, what makes them the same.

The simplest way to achieve what you want here would be to define a custom protocol/interface that does represent the generic version of the classes you will use in this application and then ensure each conforms to that and also equatable. Then you should be able to do something like:

```
var objs = Array<MyAppClassesProtocol>()
```

and also use `remove(element:)`