# Swift semantics regarding dictionary access

Tags: swift

I'm currently reading the excellent *Advanced Swift* book from objc.io, and I'm running into something that I don't understand.

If you run the following code in a playground, you will notice that when modifying a struct contained in a dictionary a copy is made by the subscript access, but then it appears that the original value in the dictionary is replaced by the copy. I don't understand why. What exactly is happening ?

Also, is there a way to avoid the copy ? According to the author of the book, there isn't, but I just want to be sure.

```swift
import Foundation

class Buffer {
    let id = UUID()
    var value = 0

    func copy() -> Buffer {
        let new = Buffer()
        new.value = self.value
        return new
    }
}

struct COWStruct {
    var buffer = Buffer()

    init() { print("Creating \(buffer.id)") }

    mutating func change() -> String {
        if isKnownUniquelyReferenced(&buffer) {
            buffer.value += 1
            return "No copy \(buffer.id)"
        } else {
            let newBuffer = buffer.copy()
            newBuffer.value += 1
            buffer = newBuffer
            return "Copy \(buffer.id)"
        }
    }
}

var array = [COWStruct()]
array[0].buffer.value
array[0].buffer.id
array[0].change()
array[0].buffer.value
array[0].buffer.id


var dict = ["key": COWStruct()]
dict["key"]?.buffer.value
dict["key"]?.buffer.id
dict["key"]?.change()
dict["key"]?.buffer.value
dict["key"]?.buffer.id

// If the above `change()` was made on a copy, why has the original value changed ?
// Did the copied & modified struct replace the original struct in the dictionary ?
```

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
dict["key"]?.change() // Copy
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
if var value = dict["key"] {
    value.change() // Copy
    dict["key"] = value
}
```

The value is pulled out of the dictionary, unwrapped into a temporary, mutated, and then placed back into the dictionary.

Because there's now *two* references to the underlying buffer (one from our local temporary `value`, and one from the `COWStruct` instance in the dictionary itself) – we're forcing a copy of the underlying `Buffer` instance, as it's no longer uniquely referenced.

So, why doesn't

```
array[0].change() // No Copy
```

do the same thing? Surely the element should be pulled out of the array, mutated and then stuck back in, replacing the previous value?

The difference is that unlike `Dictionary`'s subscript which comprises of a getter and setter, `Array`'s [subscript comprises of a getter and a special accessor](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1a1157ded52456260e5c62f1a3ac7a570118862c/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L688) called `mutableAddressWithPinnedNativeOwner`.

What this special accessor does is return a *pointer* to the element in the array's underlying buffer, along with an owner object to ensure that the buffer isn't deallocated from under the caller. Such an accessor is called an *addressor*, as it deals with addresses.

Therefore when you say:

```
array[0].change()
```

you're actually mutating the actual element in the array *directly*, rather than a temporary.

Such an addressor cannot be directly applied to `Dictionary`'s subscript because it returns an `Optional`, and the underlying value isn't stored as an optional. So it currently has to be unwrapped with a temporary, as we cannot return a pointer to the value in storage.

In Swift 3, you can avoid copying your `COWStruct`'s underlying `Buffer` by removing the value from the dictionary before mutating the temporary:

```
if var value = dict["key"] {
    dict["key"] = nil
    value.change() // No Copy
    dict["key"] = value
}
```

As now *only* the temporary has a view onto the underlying `Buffer` instance.

And, as [@dfri points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632251/swift-semantics-regarding-dictionary-access/44632875#comment76253630_44632875) in the comments, this can be reduced down to:

```
if var value = dict.removeValue(forKey: "key") {
    value.change() // No Copy
    dict["key"] = value
}
```

saving on a hashing operation.

Additionally, for convenience, you may want to consider making this into an extension method:

```
extension Dictionary {
  mutating func withValue<R>(
    forKey key: Key, mutations: (inout Value) throws -> R
  ) rethrows -> R? {
    guard var value = removeValue(forKey: key) else { return nil }
    defer {
      updateValue(value, forKey: key)
    }
    return try mutations(&value)
  }
}

// ...

dict.withValue(forKey: "key") {
  $0.change() // No copy
}
```

---

In Swift 4, you *should* be able to use the [`values`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894304-values) property of `Dictionary` in order to perform a direct mutation of the value:

```
if let index = dict.index(forKey: "key") {
    dict.values[index].change()
}
```

As the `values` property now returns a special [`Dictionary.Values`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary.values) mutable collection [that has a subscript](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1a1157ded52456260e5c62f1a3ac7a570118862c/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L2558) with an addressor (see [SE-0154](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0154-dictionary-key-and-value-collections.md) for more info on this change).

However, currently (with the version of Swift 4 that ships with Xcode 9 beta 5), this still makes a copy. This is due to the fact that both the `Dictionary` and `Dictionary.Values` instances have a view onto the underlying buffer – as the `values` computed property [is just implemented](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1a1157ded52456260e5c62f1a3ac7a570118862c/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L2449) with a getter and setter that passes around a reference to the dictionary's buffer.

So when calling the addressor, a copy of the dictionary's buffer is triggered, therefore leading to two views onto `COWStruct`'s `Buffer` instance, therefore triggering a copy of it upon `change()` being called.

I have [filed a bug over this here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5258). (**Edit:** This [has now been fixed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/19497) on master with the unofficial introduction of generalised accessors using coroutines, so will be fixed in Swift 5 – see below for more info).

---

In Swift 4.1, `Dictionary`'s `subscript(_:default:)` [now uses an addressor](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/12752), so we can efficiently mutate values so long as we supply a default value to use in the mutation.

For example:

```
dict["key", default: COWStruct()].change() // No copy
```

The `default:` parameter uses `@autoclosure` such that the default value isn't evaluated if it isn't needed (such as in this case where we know there's a value for the key).

---

#### Swift 5 and beyond

With [the unofficial introduction](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/18156) of [generalised accessors](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md#generalized-accessors) in Swift 5, two new underscored accessors have been introduced, `_read` and `_modify` which use coroutines in order to yield a value back to the caller. For `_modify`, this can be an arbitrary mutable expression.

The use of coroutines is exciting because it means that a `_modify` accessor can now perform logic both before and after the mutation. This allows them to be much more efficient when it comes to copy-on-write types, as they can for example deinitialise the value in storage while yielding a temporary mutable copy of the value that's uniquely referenced to the caller (and then reinitialising the value in storage upon control returning to the callee).

The standard library has already updated many previously inefficient APIs to make use of the new `_modify` accessor – [this includes `Dictionary`'s `subscript(_:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d904b46554ef22699ffba564502d507d420e20c9/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift#L804) which can now yield a uniquely referenced value to the caller (using the deinitialisation trick I mentioned above).

The upshot of these changes means that:

```
dict["key"]?.change() // No copy
```

will be able to perform an mutation of the value without having to make a copy in Swift 5 (you can even try this out for yourself [with a master snapshot](https://swift.org/download/#snapshots)).

Comment: An alternative (and likewise common) implementation of the (nowadays) idiomatic remove-mutate-replace operation when mutating dictionary KV-pairs in Swift 3 is to make use the [`removeValue(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1641348-removevalue) method for a combined existance check & removal, rather than performing these operations separately. E.g. `if var value = dict.removeValue(forKey: "key") { /* mutate value and re-insert */ }`. Good answer as always, interesting about your investigations of the new `Dictionary.Values` collection.

Comment: @dfri Ah yes, very good point! I have edited my answer with it :)

Comment: I just noticed that it seems as if, currently, the copy and subsequent `nil` assignment alternative might incur a (minimal?) overhead compared to the direct `removeValue(forKey:)` call, as the prior alternative, after explicitly copying the value, [seemingly also calls `removeValue(forKey:)` but discards the result for the `nil` assigment](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L1982). But maybe this is optimized away in release builds :)

Comment: @Hamish Thank you so much for this detailed answer! Concerning the "copy, mutate then replace" behavior of the dictionary, I had kind of reached the same conclusion by observing how it works. So what I really want to know is : Is this by design ? Do the Swift developers wanted this behavior instead of a behavior similar to the array ? Will it always behave like this in future versions of Swift ?

Comment: I only ask because I feel that a behavior "symetrical" with the behavior of the array would make more sense, unless there is something that I'm missing. Also, I hear the argument about the Optional return of the getter, but wouldn't a `mutableAddressWithPinnedNativeOwner` returning an optional (pointer, owner) pair have worked ? The `values` approach of Swift 4 seems cumbersome in comparison assuming it ever works without making a copy.

Comment: After reading SE-0154, it seems that removing the copy-on-write problem of the subscript setter was an alternative considered but it isn't said why it was discarded.

Comment: Happy to help @deadbeef! I do believe the implementation of `Dictionary`'s is considered "by design", although I cannot guarantee it won't change in a future version of the language. The problem with having a `mutableAddressWithPinnedNativeOwner` accessor that returns an optional is that, well first of all it would need to be a completely new accessor, as the current only deals with a known-valid pointer into a given storage, but more importantly, you wouldn't easily be able to express the removal of a value with the accessor – which is currently done by assigning `nil` to the subscript.

Comment: Effectively, you'd need 3 accessors, one for getting, one for setting (to include the ability to assign `nil`), and one to provide an optional pointer to the underlying buffer. I would imagine that the Swift team decided that such a design would be too much complexity for the benefit it brings, especially given (I believe) that `Dictionary` is the only case in the stdlib that would benefit from it.

Comment: Although I definitely agree that it's not ideal having two completely different ways of mutating a single value in a dictionary, especially as it isn't immediately obvious that mutating through subscript comes with performance implications for COW values.

Comment: @dfri I would *imagine* that the additional hashing operation needed in order to perform the subscript twice rather than `remove(forKey:)` once would be the major difference in performance between the two approaches, rather than the load and discard of the value from the subscript calling `remove(forKey:)` upon a `nil` value being set. But nonetheless would be interesting to benchmark the two to see if the difference was even noticeable to begin with!

Comment: @deadbeef Actually, from seeing [this tweet](https://twitter.com/slava_pestov/status/778488750514970624) from one of the members of the Swift team, it does look they're keen to bring addressors (accessors that deal with addresses) to `Dictionary`'s subscript, bringing it more in-line with `Array`'s.

Comment: @hamish I brought [SR-5258](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/) up with the author of SE-0154 and it is currently being looked at. With a miracle it might make Swift 4, otherwise it'll be for a subsequent minor release.

Comment: Thanks @jad6os! I do hope it makes it in for Swift 4(.1).

Comment: @deadbeef Some good news; [I pushed through a change](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/12752) to `Dictionary`'s `subscript(_:default:)` such that it now uses an addressor, allowing for direct mutations of the dictionary's values through it :) All things going well, it will be a part of Swift 4.1 (you can try it out in a 4.1 snapshot if you want). Although unfortunately, the situation remains the same as before for `subscript(_:)` and `.values`.

Comment: Once the rules around strict aliasing are formalised, it's possible that fixing `.values` will be pretty straightforward. But I'm pretty sure that fixing `subscript(_:)` would require a new kind of addressor (one that deals specifically with optionals).

Comment: @Hamish Nice work! I'll definitely look for this in Swift 4.1. Still looking forward to this working on `subscript(_:)` as well though.

Comment: Thanks @Hamish, I wasn't aware of all these new developments in Swift 5, this looks very promising!