# When is the modify method of a computed property called and what does it do?

Tags: swift, getter-setter

Consider the following class definition

```
class Class1 {
    var property: String {
        get {
            return ""
        }
        set {
            print("set called")
        }
    }
}
```

If you add breakpoint inside the get block and read `property`, the execution is paused and you observe that the topmost method in the call stack is `Class1.property.getter`

Similarly, if you add breakpoint inside the set block and set `property`, the execution is paused and you observe that the topmost method in the call stack is `Class1.property.setter`

While debugging a crash, I observed that the topmost method in the call stack was `ClassName.computedPropertyName.modify` where `ClassName` and `computedPropertyName` are placeholders.

Can anyone point out what the `modify` method does and when it is called?

Comment: Are you getting the crash in `property`?

Comment: The code that is present in the question is only for illustration purpose. I observed a crash in an app that I wrote. When I observed the call stack at the time of the crash, I saw that the top of the stack was the `modify` method of a computed property which had getter and setter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like `get` and `set`, `modify` is an accessor. It's a part of the move towards [generalised accessors](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md#generalized-accessors), and is used to obtain a mutable reference to an underlying value using a yield-once coroutine.

You can actually write `modify` accessors in today's Swift using the `_modify` keyword. Though note however that it's not yet an official feature, so any code that explicitly depends on `_modify` and `yield` is subject to breaking without notice.

```
class C {
  var _property: String = ""
  var property: String {
    get {
      return _property
    }
    _modify {
      yield &_property
    }
  }
}

let c = C()
c.property += "hello"
print(c.property) // hello
```

Upon mutating `c.property`, the `_modify` accessor is called to obtain a mutable reference to some underlying storage. The `yield` keyword is used in order to transfer control back to the caller with a reference to `_property`'s storage. At this point, the caller can apply arbitrary mutations to the storage, in this case calling `+=`. Once the mutation has finished, control is transferred back to `_modify`, at which point it returns.

#### Why is the `modify` accessor useful?

Simply put, it avoids the copying of values, which can trigger expensive copying operations for copy-on-write types such as `String`, `Array`, and `Dictionary` (I talk about this [in more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632251/swift-semantics-regarding-dictionary-access/44632875#44632875)). Mutating `c.property` through a `modify` accessor allows the string to be mutated in-place, rather than mutating a temporary copy which is then written back.

#### Why does `modify` use coroutines?

The use of a coroutine allows a mutable reference to be temporarily handed back to the caller, after which the accessor can then perform additional logic.

For example:

```
class C {
  var _property: String = ""
  var property: String {
    get {
      return _property
    }
    _modify {
      yield &_property
      _property += " world!"
    }
  }
}

let c = C()
c.property += "hello"
print(c.property) // hello world!
```

which first lets the caller perform its mutations, and then appends `" world!"` to the end of the string.

#### Why is the `modify` accessor showing up in your code?

The Swift compiler can implicitly synthesise a `modify` accessor for mutable properties. For a computed property with a getter and setter, the implementation looks like this:

```
class Class1 {
  var property: String {
    get {
      return ""
    }
    set {
      print("set called")
    }
    // What the compiler synthesises:
    _modify {
      var tmp = property.get() // Made up syntax.
      yield &tmp
      property.set(tmp)
    }
  }
}
```

The getter is first called in order to get a mutable copy of the value, a reference to this mutable copy is then passed back to the caller, and then the setter is called with the new value.

The `modify` accessor is primarily used in this case in order to enable efficient mutation of a property through dynamic dispatch. Consider the following example:

```
class C {
  var property = "hello" {
    // What the compiler synthesises:
    _modify {
      yield &property
    }
  }
}

class D : C {
  override var property: String {
    get { return "goodbye" }
    set { print(newValue) }
    // What the compiler synthesises:
    _modify {
      var tmp = property.get()
      yield &tmp
      property.set(tmp)
    }
  }
}

func mutateProperty(_ c: C) {
  c.property += "foo"
}
```

On mutating `c.property`, the `modify` accessor is dynamically dispatched to. If this is an instance of `C`, this allows a reference to the storage of `property` to be directly returned to the caller, allowing for an efficient in-place mutation. If this is an instance of `D`, then calling the `modify` just has the same effect as calling the getter followed by the setter.

#### Why is `modify` showing up as the topmost call in the stack trace of your crash?

I would assume this is because the compiler has inlined the implementation of your getter and setter into the `modify` accessor, therefore meaning that the crash has likely been caused by the implementation of either the getter or setter of your property.

Answer (score 0):

`modify` is called anytime you change the value of the property. So for a string it would be anytime you set, update or remove the value of said string.

The following would be an example of when modify is called.

```
var string: String? //modify not called here 
string = “new string”
string = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

- pieces of code which will call every time when you assign them.
- Computed properties are always variables

**get { }** : When retrieving the value of a property this block of code will get executed.

**set { }** : When setting the value of a property this part of code will get executed.

**Example**

```
var center: Point {
    get {
        let centerX = origin.x + (size.width / 2)
        let centerY = origin.y + (size.height / 2)
        return Point(x: centerX, y: centerY)
    }
    set(newCenter) {
        origin.x = newCenter.x - (size.width / 2)
        origin.y = newCenter.y - (size.height / 2)
    }
}
```

[Swift Property Document](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)