# Why `String(describing: Class.self)` is slower than `NSStringFromClass(Class.self)`?

Tags: swift, performance

Consider the following programm:

```
import Foundation
import QuartzCore

class C: NSObject {}

func benchmark() {
    let swift1 = CACurrentMediaTime()
    let swiftString = String(describing: C.self)
    let swift2 = CACurrentMediaTime()

    let objc1 = CACurrentMediaTime()
    let objcString = NSStringFromClass(C.self)
    let objc2 = CACurrentMediaTime()

    let timeForSwiftString = swift2 - swift1
    let timeForObjcString = objc2 - objc1
    print("timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString:", timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString)
}

for _ in 0..<20 {
    benchmark()
}
```

The output will look something like

```
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 21.023079257409023
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 1.8032004909527086
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 2.929076507541501
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 3.1707763580662034
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 2.884789101770234
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 3.167761588431754
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 3.0066055331053776
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 3.0707174733951255
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 3.213085166384659
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 2.830997374357457
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 3.24157236450268
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 3.0462955824531646
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 2.887874789238326
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 3.1071486398963732
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 2.995876045716979
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 3.073833893272912
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 2.965068621921414
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 3.0622197750334306
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 3.0484172031541656
timeForSwiftString / timeForObjcString: 1.9362930766842597
```

The first measurement is always the most expensive (perhaps due to some lazy runtime actions), so we will skip it.

All other measurements show, that swift is slower.

I also have a [demo project](https://github.com/Usipov/StringFromClassTests) with a benchmark on getting string from 1000 different classes which shows:

- Swift's `String(describing: Class.self)` works slower, than Objective-C's `NSClassFromString(Class.self)` (30..150μs vs 4..12μs)
- Calling Swift's `String(describing: Class.self)` on different classes gets slower and slower with every new class,
  while Objective-C times remain the same

Any ideas for such a behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re comparing apples with motorcars.

- `NSStringFromClass` does a highly specific job, involving only class types, and is used for a conversion related to the dynamic nature of Objective-C programs.
- `String(describing:)` in Swift turns *anything* into a string representation and is intended (and suitable) only for *debugging*. It will not be used for any user-facing code and no meaningful program action will depend upon its output. Thus it will not appear in a released app and its speed is of no account. Your question therefore optimizes not only prematurely but unnecessarily; the speed of `String(describing:)` is unimportant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I ask this, bucause I want to optimize some code in a library for dependency injection in swift. This code uses `String(describing:)` for creating dictionary keys depending on the Type description: https://github.com/AliSoftware/Dip/blob/815e9ccd6660d7f0084334edc1105a803968acfc/Sources/Definition.swift#L38. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: We cannot use `NSStringFromClass`, because the types we create keys from are always protocol types. We could use `NSStringFromProtocol`, but it would require us to make all protocols `@objc`, which is imposibble for most of our protocols (they use pure swift types, associated types and other swift stuff)

Comment: If we could make Types conform to `Hashable`... This would solve all the problems, but seems to be impossible to implement, because afaic only type instances can conform to `Hashable`

Comment: @Tim You can use `ObjectIdentifier`, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/42459484/2976878

Comment: Hi @Tim The trouble in that case is that this becomes an “xy” question. Please ask a full new question describing the problem you were _really_ trying to solve all along! Thanks. I stand by my assertion, though, that if you are thinking of using `String(describing:)` in production code, you’re doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

> perhaps due to some lazy runtime actions

Spot on, first calls to anything can be slower for various reasons including resolution of dynamically loaded libraries.

> Any ideas for such a behavior?

A first guess would be that `String(describing:)` takes *any* value, figures out what kind of value it is (it's description states it tests for conformance to three different protocols), and then calls the appropriate functions to describe the value. However `NSStringFromClass` takes only `Class` values, which is checked at compile time, and then directly calls the runtime functions needed to get the class name as a string without any need for testing and branching on the kind of value passed.

TLDR: More work takes more time, testing and branching slows you down.

HTH