# CS0019 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'bool'

Tags: c#

I am doing a C# course and this is a part of it. I am getting this error message:

> CS0019    Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'bool'

The code:

```
OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if(openDialogue.ShowDialog == true) { //Code to run; } ....
```

Unfortunately I don't understand the error and how I can correct it.

Comment: `ShowDialog` is a function, call it using `ShowDialog()`

Comment: Here's the documentation on the method if you require more explanation about the method itself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ShowDialog

Comment: Welcome new user.   Users, no need to downvote **simple** questions. It's a good, simple question.

Comment: This question has utterly no connection to a typo, and it is flawlessly reproducible.  Don't close vote.

Comment: Leaving out two parentheses, which were surly there when OP did the course clearly is a typo. Failing to properly read the error message and/or to read the docs of `ShowDialog ` or do any reasearch is not exactly a sign of a good question. And, just as obviously it is not a useful addition to SO; so it should be deleted asap! ((But your answer indeed is a really good one, although wasted on a bad question))

Comment: @TaW , I have to respectfully disagree.  Simple questions are ***not*** "outlawed" on SO.  A typo is when for example you type "Sohw" instead of "Show".  A classic (basic, beginner) programming mistake or misunderstanding is confusing the difference between variables, functions, lambdas and other concepts.  (Actually, I do this all the time when I lazily rely on code completion! heh!)  I do understand that many thoughtful SO folks, such as yourself, are "anti-" simple/beginner questions; I'm afraid I can't agree!  Have a good one ... fatster

Comment: @TaW here's me asking basically the identical question :)  https://stackoverflow.com/q/42459484/294884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two simple problems:

```
openDialogue.ShowDialog
```

should be

```
openDialogue.ShowDialog()
```

and

```
true
```

should be

```
DialogResult.OK
```

A great tip is, MSFT has **incredibly voluminous documentation**.

I literally typed in to a browser **"c# openDialogue.ShowDialog"**

and immediately got:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netcore-3.1

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  And thank you for the tip.  One of the problems that I have is that I have some difficulty knowing what question to ask.  Aquestion I still have though:  Is saying "DialogResult.OK" the same as saying "true"?

Comment: it is not the same, no!  @KevBurgess  great question, good luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to write by adding `()` to the `ShowDialog`:

```
if ( openDialogue.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
```

Because it is a [method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm) call.

And it returns a `DialogResult` value.

If you had created a form, and you don't use a premade dialog box, you need to specify some things in the form to return a value like `OK` or `Cancel` because the default is `None`. For example you can use some buttons click events and set the `DialogResult` of the form, or use the properties of the form `CancelButton` and `AcceptButton`.

[Form.ShowDialog Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog)

[Form.DialogResult Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult)