# Selecting a random value from a subsection of an enum

Tags: swift, enums

Given a Swift enum as such:

```
enum PerformerPosition: Int {

    case String_Violin1
    case String_Violin2
    case String_Viola
    case String_Cello
    case String_CB

    case Wind_Oboe
    case Wind_Clarinet
    case Wind_Flute
    ...

}
```

(For the needs of the project, I am **not** able to have a nested enum.) I would like to randomly select an enum value with the `String_` prefix, only.

The only way I know so far is to do a random enum value from all the available cases, as such:

```
private static let _count: PerformerPosition.RawValue = {
    // find the maximum enum value
    var maxValue: Int = 0
    while let _ = PerformerPosition(rawValue: maxValue) { 
        maxValue += 1
    }
    return maxValue
}()

static func randomPerformer() -> PerformerPosition {
    // pick and return a new value
    let rand = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count))
    return PlayerPosition(rawValue: Int(rand))!
}
```

How could I make it so I am able to pick a random value based on the `String_` prefix only **without** having to resort to hard-coding an upper value (for example, new `String_` prefix positions may be added)? Thanks

Comment: Does the raw value have to be `UInt32`?

Comment: Nope - it could just be a regular `Int`. I'll update. FYI `arc4random` needs `UInt32`. The appropriate typecast has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't want to change any of the code even if a new position is added. Right?

To do that, you need to get all the enum cases dynamically, instead of hardcoding them. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32429125/5133585), you can use this method to get all the cases:

```
protocol EnumCollection : Hashable {}
extension EnumCollection {
    static func cases() -> AnySequence<Self> {
        typealias S = Self
        return AnySequence { () -> AnyIterator<S> in
            var raw = 0
            return AnyIterator {
                let current : Self = withUnsafePointer(to: &raw) { $0.withMemoryRebound(to: S.self, capacity: 1) { $0.pointee } }
                guard current.hashValue == raw else { return nil }
                raw += 1
                return current
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After you got this `cases` method, you can easily get what you want by:

```
let startingWithString = Array(PerformerPosition.cases().filter { "\($0)".hasPrefix("String_") })
let rand = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(startingWithString.count))
let randomPosition = startingWithString[Int(rand)]
```

Comment: Great solution, and thanks for pointing out the bit about how to get access to all the cases.

Comment: This is a working solution but I would consider this a very dirty solution.

Comment: @Sulthan It is. But the OP seems to not want to change code in parallel when he/she add new enum cases, so that's why I gave this solution.

Comment: It is more resource intensive. However, at the moment I cannot change the data structure and it definitely solves the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

If you have different subsets in your enum and you need to access them separately, I would recommend to identify the subsets somehow, consider:

```
enum PerformerPosition: Int {

    case String_Violin1
    case String_Violin2
    case String_Viola
    case String_Cello
    case String_CB

    case Wind_Oboe
    case Wind_Clarinet
    case Wind_Flute

    static let strings: [PerformerPosition] = [
        .String_Violin1, .String_Violin2, .String_Viola, .String_Cello, .String_CB
    ]

    static let winds: [PerformerPosition] = [
        .Wind_Oboe, .Wind_Clarinet, .String_Viola, .Wind_Flute
    ]
}
```

Note that this will enable you several things:

1. You won't need the `String_` and `Wind_` prefixes. You can simply use `.violin1`, `.oboe`, etc.
2. You can simply generate random position from your array
3. You can directly check the type of your position:

   ```
   let isString = PerformerPosition.strings.contains(.violin1)
   ```

Comment: This is a very helpful suggestion to a potentially more optimal data structure and the type checking is esp helpful. Thanks for suggesting this

Answer (score 0):

I made this in PlayGround:

```
func randomPerformer() -> PerformerPosition {
    // pick and return a new value
    let rand = arc4random_uniform(_count)
    let string = String(describing:PerformerPosition(rawValue: rand))
    if(string.contains("String_")){
            return PerformerPosition(rawValue: rand)!
    }else{
            return randomPerformer()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good first step. My issue is that `rand` still takes into account all of the performers (including those who do not have the `String_` prefix). While it will call upon `randomPerformer()` again if the outcome is not satisfactory, I would want to solve the issue in the `rand` part. Maybe There needs to be a dedicated `randString`.

Comment: Yes, i didnt understood what you really wanted, sorry