# Get generic Array of RawRepresentable from AnyIterator

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I saw this answer [How to enumerate an enum with String type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341290/5561910)

Now I'm trying to create method that will return array of strings
with the raw values of the enum.

So I did :

```
class func enumValues<T>(from array: AnyIterator<T>) -> [T] where T:RawRepresentable, T:Hashable {
    var tempArray = [T]()
    for item in array{
        tempArray.append(item.rawValue)
    }
    return tempArray
}
```

But, i get this error :

> Argument type 'T.RawValue' does not conform to expected type
> 'Hashable'
>
> Argument type 'T.RawValue' does not conform to expected type
> 'RawRepresentable'

How can i fix this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return an array with the raw values of the array elements,
so the return type should be `T.RawValue` (and the constraint
`T:Hashable` is not needed):

```
func enumValues<T>(from array: AnyIterator<T>) -> [T.RawValue] where T: RawRepresentable {
    var tempArray: [T.RawValue] = []
    for item in array{
        tempArray.append(item.rawValue)
    }
    return tempArray
}
```

which can be simplified to

```
func enumValues<T>(from array: AnyIterator<T>) -> [T.RawValue] where T: RawRepresentable {
    return array.map { $0.rawValue }
}
```

or more generally for any sequence of raw-representables:

```
func enumValues<S: Sequence>(from sequence: S) -> [S.Iterator.Element.RawValue]
    where S.Iterator.Element: RawRepresentable {

    return sequence.map { $0.rawValue }
}
```

On the other hand one may ask if this is worth a separate function
at all, since you can call `map { $0.rawValue }` directly on the
given iterator/sequence/array.

Answer (score 1):

To return array of strings with the raw values of the enum all you need to do is to conform to `CaseIterable`.

```
enum WeekDay: String, CaseIterable {
    case monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday
}

let arrayOfRawValues = WeekDay.allCases.map(\.rawValue)
```