# How can a certain structure be retrieved from a group of structures?

Tags: swift, struct

So let's say I have a structure consisting of three elements - SPEED_OF_LIGHT, SPEED_OF_SOUND, and SPEED_OF_PERSON as shown below:

```
public struct Fast {
    public let speed: Double

    private init(speed: Double) {
        self.speed = speed
    }

    public static let SPEED_OF_LIGHT = Fast(speed: 300000000)
    public static let SPEED_OF_SOUND = Fast(speed: 340)
    public static let SPEED_OF_PERSON = Fast(speed: 1.5)
}
```

If I have a double of let's say 340, how would I iterate through all of the possibilities until I find the correct match? To show exactly what I mean, I have a working code snippet that does what I want. This is done *in Java*.

```
public enum Fast {
    SPEED_OF_LIGHT(300000000),
    SPEED_OF_SOUND(340),
    SPEED_OF_PERSON(1.5);

    private double speed;

    private Fast(double speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public static Fast getFast(double speed) {
        for (Fast f : Fast.values()) {
            if (f.speed == speed) return f;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

In the above case, calling getFast(340) would return SPEED_OF_SOUND. How would I do something similarly in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use an enum (Swift has them too), but there is no equivalent to the `values()` function you call to get the list.

You would have to add an array member to the enum with the full list -- it would be a repetition of the cases, so a little error prone.

See this answer for details on how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24137319/3937

There are tricks/hacks to try to get something like `values`, but it's different for each version of swift and not worth the trouble in my opinion.