# Why get wrong hashValue from Enum from Xcode 10? Is it Apple's bug?

Tags: swift, xcode10.1

**Update:**

I met this problem because I use the hashValue for get Enum count as Antonio's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27094973/3367915) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094878/how-do-i-get-the-count-of-a-swift-enum/27094973#27094973).

And also, Antonio's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27094973/3367915) works well before Xcode 10, I just want to know why the result is changed now.

---

### Original question

Environment:
macOS 10.14.1

The same enum, the Xcode 10.1 return the enum item's hashValue as 4607296766572878277, the Xcode 9.4.1 returns 0:

Code:

```
enum IntEnum: Int {
    case first = 1, second
}

let x = IntEnum.first.hashValue

print("first hashValue \(x)")

enum strEnum: String {
    case first, second
}

let a = strEnum.first.hashValue
```

Xcode 10.1:
[image]

Xcode 9.4.1:
[image]

Is this Apple's bug?

Comment: Please post actual code and not images of code.

Comment: Why do you expect the hash value to be the same? From the documentation for `hashValue`: *"Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions of your program. Do not save hash values to use during a future execution."*

Comment: Related: [Is it sensible to rely on hashValue for enum cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266779/is-it-sensible-to-rely-on-hashvalue-for-enum-cases?s=4|42.1422)

Comment: Better this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205254/xcode-9-and-xcode-10-giving-different-results-even-with-same-swift-version (which is in comment of the linked question). It changed, but question is what do you want to do with it, and why should it be the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 9 and Xcode 10 giving different results, even with same swift version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205254/xcode-9-and-xcode-10-giving-different-results-even-with-same-swift-version)

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Check my answer to get indexValue on following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/54548695/6808061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all guys's answer. As rmaddy's said the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/1540917-hashvalue) as below:
[image]

So do not use hashValue during a future execution.