# Copying ENUM hash and raw values into a dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, enums, associative-array

Is there any way to copy all the values of an enumeration into a dictionary without polling them in any **FOR** loop?

For example, from this enumeration:

```
enum FruitPriority: String {
    case PEARS
    case ORANGES
    case APPLES
}
```

to call some single function from within the ENUM, something like this:

```
var fruitPriorityArray: [String : Int] = FruitPriority.someFunction()
```

and get this result *(sorted according to hash value)*:

```
["PEARS": 0, "ORANGES": 1, "APPLES": 2]
```

The preference would be to ***make only a single call to the ENUM.***

Thank you.

Comment: An “associative array” is called *dictionary* in Swift. A dictionary is an *unordered* collection of key/value pairs.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for your prompt answer. You're right. So, would it be possible to accomplish this *unordered?*

Comment: Why would you need it like that? Why not just change the raw value to an `Int` and use the raw value instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
enum FruitPriority: String, CaseIterable {
    case PEARS
    case ORANGES
    case APPLES
}

let result = FruitPriority.allCases.enumerated().reduce([String: Int]()) { dict, fruit in
    var dict = dict
    dict[fruit.element.rawValue] = fruit.offset
    return dict
}

print(result)
```

The result is:

> ["PEARS": 0, "ORANGES": 1, "APPLES": 2]

For version Swift 4.1 and earlier the implementation of `CaseIterable`:

```
#if swift(>=4.2)
#else
public protocol CaseIterable {
    associatedtype AllCases: Collection where AllCases.Element == Self
    static var allCases: AllCases { get }
}
extension CaseIterable where Self: Hashable {
    static var allCases: [Self] {
        return [Self](AnySequence { () -> AnyIterator<Self> in
            var raw = 0
            return AnyIterator {
                let current = withUnsafeBytes(of: &raw) { $0.load(as: Self.self) }
                guard current.hashValue == raw else {
                    return nil
                }
                raw += 1
                return current
            }
        })
    }
}
#endif
```

Original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49588446/1979882) of `CaseIterable` implementation.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm sorry that I didn't mention that I'm not able to use Swift 4.2, as my dev machine is stuck on High Sierra. Xcode 10 requires Mojave. Could this be done without ***CaseIterable***?

Comment: @iSofia You can implement CaseIterable in version earlier

Comment: Really!? I wasn't aware. I'll give it a try. Thanks again Vyacheslav.

Comment: Don't forget to add a link to the original implementation of the CaseIterable implementation, for proper attribution.

Comment: @MartinR I found it several months ago at StackOverflow. Now I've just copied from my own code. I don't really remember the source. But I'll try

Comment: It works! Thank you, Vyacheslav. Especially for the Swift 4.1 workaround.

Comment: I found the original implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49588446/1630618

Comment: @vacawama added Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just single call to the enum:

Add `CaseIterable` to your enum and then just create function `getDictionary` in enum which returns you dictionary (for each enum case will be `rawValue` assigned as `key` and `hashValue` as `value` )

```
enum FruitPriority: String, CaseIterable {

    case PEARS
    case ORANGES
    case APPLES

    func getDictionary() -> [String: Int] {
        var dictionary = [String: Int]()
        FruitPriority.allCases.forEach {
            dictionary[$0.rawValue] = $0.hashValue
        }
        return dictionary
    }

}
```

then you can just call

```
var fruitPriorityArray: [String : Int] = FruitPriority.getDictionary()
```

**Note:** if you're using earlier versions of Swift you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007461/how-to-enumerate-an-enum-with-string-type) to create `CaseIterable` protocol

Comment: Thank you, Robert Dresler. I'll try to implement the protocol you'd recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your enum `CaseIterable`, you can construct a dictionary using `reduce(into:)`.  Since the `hashValue` can now change from run to run, I would recommend using `enumerated()` to number the cases in order:

```
enum FruitPriority: String, CaseIterable {
    case PEARS
    case ORANGES
    case APPLES
}

let result = FruitPriority.allCases.enumerated().reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.element.rawValue] = $1.offset }

print(result)

// ["ORANGES": 1, "APPLES": 2, "PEARS": 0]
```

Comment: Thank you, vacawama, for the tip on ***reduce into.*** I'm trying to implement it as it seems so much simpler.