# Pass and print all cases in an enum in Swift

Tags: swift, enums, iteration, parameter-passing

Consider this simple enum:

```
enum myEnum: String {
    case abc = "ABC"
    case xyz = "XYZ"
}
```

I want to write a function that can print all cases in an enum. Like..

```
printEnumCases(myEnum)
```

Expected result:

```
ABC
XYZ
```

Note: I can able to iterate an enum like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49588446/1389515). But I don't know how to pass the enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a generic function which takes a type as argument which is `CaseIterable` and `RawRepresentable`:

```
func printEnumCases<T>(_: T.Type) where T: CaseIterable & RawRepresentable {
    for c in T.allCases {
        print(c.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
enum MyEnum: String, CaseIterable {
    case abc = "ABC"
    case xyz = "XYZ"
}

printEnumCases(MyEnum.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your enum conform to `CaseIterable` and then you'll be able to use `.allCases`.

```
enum myEnum: String, CaseIterable {
    case abc = "ABC"
    case xyz = "XYZ"
}

myEnum.allCases.forEach { x -> print(x.rawValue) }
```

[CaseIterable docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable)