# Is there a Swift equivalent to the 'Filter' function in Python?

Tags: python, swift, unicode, lambda, swift-playground

In python, it is incredibly simple to remove unwanted items from a string/list using the 'filter' function which can be used in conjunction with 'lambda' functions. in python, it's as simple as:

```
a = "hello 123 bye-bye !!£$%$%"
b = list(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), a))
c = "".join(b)
print(c) #Which would print "hellobyebye"
```

Is there any way to easily replicate this in swift without first converting to unicode and then checking if the unicode value is within a certain range? Also, are there any 'lambda' like things in swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List comprehension in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003584/list-comprehension-in-swift)

Comment: Note: the list comprehension in the above link includes a filtering expression.

Comment: i'm not 100% sure on how this would work. could you elaborate?

Comment: The linked question and answers seem pretty clear to me, and I've been learning Swift for about five minutes (for this question). I think you need to spend some time with [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) or a tutorial.

Comment: btw, `''.join(x for x in a if x.isalpha())`. There are situations where I use `map` and `filter`, but if you're using them *with a lambda* then the equivalent comprehension almost always reads better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is an equivalant `Filter` function in Swift:

> **Filter**
>
> The filter method takes a function (includeElement) which, given an
>   element in the array, returns a Bool indicating whether the element
>   should be included in the resulting array. For example, removing all
>   the odd numbers from the numbers array could be done like this:
>
> ```
> let numbers = [ 10000, 10303, 30913, 50000, 100000, 101039, 1000000 ]
> let evenNumbers = numbers.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
> // [ 10000, 50000, 100000, 1000000 ]
> ```

More about [Map, Filter and Reduce in Swift](http://www.electricpeelsoftware.com/2014/08/12/map-filter-reduce.html)

Comment: What does the '$0' do? does this act as a placeholder for each individual list element?

Comment: Please see [the documentation on closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94), under the section titled "Shorthand Argument Names."