# Can the concept of list comprehension be implemented in Swift?

Tags: swift, haskell, list-comprehension

I've been studying the Swift programming language for iOS, and I have a very small Haskell background. I'm very curious to know if the concept of list comprehension can be implemented in Swift?

Any thoughts, advice, etc., would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI, list comprehensions are not haskell exclusive. Python has them as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, list comprehensions are a syntactic feature that a language either has or doesn't have.  Swift doesn't have them.  For some concise ways of achieving similar results, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003584/list-comprehension-in-swift).

Comment: This should have been marked as a duplicate, rather than posting an answer that links to another post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I voted to close it as a duplicate of that question.  I submitted the answer in case there weren't four other votes agreeing with me..