# Filtering futures using values in another future

Tags: scala, future

I have two futures. 
One future (`idsFuture`) holds the computation to get the list of ids. The type of the `idsFuture` is `Future[List[Int]]`

Another Future(`dataFuture`) holds an array of `A` where `A` is defined as `case class A(id: Int, data: String)`. The type of `dataFuture` is Future[Array[A]]

I want to filter `dataFuture`'s using ids present in idsFuture.

For example-

```
 case class A(id: Int, data: String)
 val dataFuture = Future(Array(A(1,"a"), A(2,"b"), A(3,"c")))
 val idsFuture = Future(List(1,2))
```

I should get another future having Array((A(1,"a"), A(2,"b"))

I currently do

```
idsFuture.flatMap{
   ids => dataFuture.map(datas => datas.filter(data => ids.contains(data.id)))}
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Better in what sense? Do you perceive a problem with the solution you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [for-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/406435) here instead of `flatMap` + `map` like this:

```
for {
  ds <- dataFuture
  idsList <- idsFuture
  ids = idsList.toSet
} yield ds filter { d => ids(d.id) }
```

Note that `apply` on `Set` is faster then `contains` on `List`.