# For loop inside a .map() in scala: return type is "Unit"

Tags: scala

*EDIT: I found this [What is Scala's yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/what-is-scalas-yield) (particularly the second, most popular, answer) to be very instructive after the accepted answer solved my problem.*

==

I have a HashMap, which I want to iterate in, and for each keys, use a for loop to create new objects.

I'm trying to get a list of those new objects, but I'm always given back an empty "Unit" sequence. I'd like to understand better the behaviour of my code.

```
case class MyObject(one: String, two: String, three: Int)

val hm = new HashMap[String,Int]

hm += ("key" -> 3)
hm += ("key2" -> 4)

val newList = hm.map { case (key,value) =>
  for (i <- 0 until value) {
    new MyObject(key, "a string", i)
  }}.toSeq
```

result:

```
newList:Seq[Unit] = ArrayBuffer((), ())
```

If I don't use any for loop inside the .map(), I have the type of structure I'm expecting:

```
val newList = hm.map { case (key,value) =>
    new MyObject(key, "a string", value)}.toSeq
```

results in:

```
 newList:Seq[MyObject] = ArrayBuffer(MyObject(key,host,3), MyObject(key2,host,4))
```

Comment: What result type did you expect?

Comment: You are missing the `yield` keyword on your `map` statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you are missing `yield` on the for comprehension in your `map` statement.  If you do not include the `yield` keyword then your for comprehension is purely side effecting and does not produce anything.  Change it to:

```
for (i <- 0 until value) yield {
```

Now from here, you will end up with a `Seq[IndexedSeq[MyObject]]`.  If you want to end up with just a `Seq[MyObject]` then you can `flatten` like so:

```
val newList = hm.map { case (key,value) =>
  for (i <- 0 until value) yield {
    MyObject(key, "a string", i)
  }}.toSeq.flatten
}
```

And in fact (as pointed out by @KarolS), you can shorten this even further by replacing `map` with `flatMap` and remove the explicit `flatten` at the end:

```
val newList = hm.flatMap { case (key,value) =>
  for (i <- 0 until value) yield {
    MyObject(key, "a string", i)
  }}.toSeq
}
```

Comment: Instead of `.map(...).flatten` you can usually do `.flatMap(...)`, and usually it's faster too.